# Can't install do_mysql gem?

Tags: mysql, ruby, macos, rubygems

I'm trying to install the do_mysql on my Snow Leopord system Macbook Pro 13", but I keep getting this error:

```
n216-160:~ myself$ sudo gem1.9 install do_mysql
Password:
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing do_mysql:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

/opt/local/bin/ruby1.9 extconf.rb
checking for mysql_query() in -lmysqlclient... no
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of
necessary libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more
details.  You may need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
    --with-opt-dir
    --without-opt-dir
    --with-opt-include
    --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
    --with-opt-lib
    --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
    --with-make-prog
    --without-make-prog
    --srcdir=.
    --curdir
    --ruby=/opt/local/bin/ruby1.9
    --with-mysql-config
    --without-mysql-config
    --with-mysql-dir
    --without-mysql-dir
    --with-mysql-include
    --without-mysql-include=${mysql-dir}/include
    --with-mysql-lib
    --without-mysql-lib=${mysql-dir}/lib
    --with-mysqlclientlib
    --without-mysqlclientlib


Gem files will remain installed in /opt/local/lib/ruby1.9/gems/1.9.1/gems/do_mysql-0.10.0 for inspection.
Results logged to /opt/local/lib/ruby1.9/gems/1.9.1/gems/do_mysql-0.10.0/ext/do_mysql_ext/gem_make.out
n216-160:~ myself$
```

I have no idea why. I also reinstalled my verison of MySQL with the MySQL 5.4.3 beta, 64-bit as others suggested but no dice. Does anyone have any idea what is wrong?

Answer (score 24):

You are missing libmysqlclient-dev package. On Deb systems you could install this using

```
sudo apt-get install libmysqlclient-dev
```

Not sure about mac (maybe "sudo port install libmysqlclient-dev" ?)

Comment: RPM equivalent: `sudo yum install mysql-devel`

Comment: or `brew install mysql` http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3608287/installing-mysql2-gem-for-rails-3

Comment: Macports - `port install mysql5 +server`

Answer (score 9):

I had the same issue, and the above solution did not work until I fixed my $PATH:
PATH="/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:$PATH" # if not already present
PATH="$PATH:/usr/local/mysql/bin"
export PATH=$PATH

Answer (score 7):

```
sudo env ARCHFLAGS="-arch x86_64" gem install do_mysql -- --with-mysql-dir=/usr/local/mysql/
```

Comment: This is the most useful thing ever.

Answer (score 2):

Try this

`sudo env ARCHFLAGS="-arch x86_64"

 gem install do_mysql --with-mysql-dir=/usr/local/mysql/ --ruby=/opt/local/bin/ruby1.9`

You have to specify the location of your mysql installation, as well as the location of the ruby installation, since you are using ruby1.9, I am assuming you may have 1.8 running as well on your machine.

Answer (score 2):

You require both Mysql to be installed and the path to the Mysql binary added to your profile.

1) Download and install the MySQL binary (make sure you pick the correct CPU architecture).

2) Edit the file `~/.profile` and add `:/usr/local/mysql/bin` to your path.

3) In a new terminal window do `sudo gem install do_mysql`

Hope that helps!

Cheers,

Marcus