# Ruby gem mysql2 install error

Tags: ruby, installation, rubygems

I have the Ruby version ruby 1.9.2p0 (2010-08-18) [i386-mingw32] installed in Windows7. 
and the gem vesion 1.3.7

When i tried to install mysql gem, it is showing `Failed to build gem native extension` error, why is this? my mysql version is 5.1.36(WampServer)

```
E:\RubyApps\test_app2>gem install mysql2
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing mysql2:
        ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

E:/Ruby192/bin/ruby.exe extconf.rb
checking for rb_thread_blocking_region()... *** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of
necessary libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more
details.  You may need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
        --with-opt-dir
        --without-opt-dir
        --with-opt-include
        --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
        --with-opt-lib
        --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
        --with-make-prog
        --without-make-prog
        --srcdir=.
        --curdir
        --ruby=E:/Ruby192/bin/ruby
E:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:368:in `try_do': The complier failed to genera
te an executable file. (RuntimeError)
You have to install development tools first.
        from E:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:435:in `try_link0'
        from E:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:440:in `try_link'
        from E:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:552:in `try_func'
        from E:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:797:in `block in have_func'
        from E:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:693:in `block in checking_for'
        from E:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:280:in `block (2 levels) in postp
one'
        from E:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:254:in `open'
        from E:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:280:in `block in postpone'
        from E:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:254:in `open'
        from E:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:276:in `postpone'
        from E:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:692:in `checking_for'
        from E:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:796:in `have_func'
        from extconf.rb:9:in `<main>'


Gem files will remain installed in E:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/mysql2-0.
2.3 for inspection.
Results logged to E:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/mysql2-0.2.3/ext/mysql2/ge
m_make.out

E:\RubyApps\test_app2>
```

Comment: if you still have problems (i did) gem install mysql2 -v 0.2.6

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Since this keeps coming up on google as on of the top results, I should point out that this answers is from almost 2 years ago. Here is a more updated answer: [How to use "mysql2" gem in Rails 3 application on Windows 7?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5775344/how-to-use-mysql2-gem-in-rails-3-application-on-windows-7/7313694#7313694)**

---

According to the developer there is a already a reported bug for it and he is working on parting mysql2 over to Windows. As of now - it's still in the works. Use the older mysql driver for now - or use sqlite for local development.

This is from the googlegroups discussion

> Blockquote
>   Hey Erwann,
>   There's a ticket on the mysql2 issue tracker for Win32 support already
>   at http://github.com/brianmario/mysql2/issues#issue/8 . You can follow
>   it for progress; I'm doing my best to get things working smoothly for
>   you guys. Hang tight! :)

Answer (score 34):

If you are having this same problem in Linux, basically you just need to install a few libraries first. This worked for me.

```
> sudo apt-get install libmysql-ruby libmysqlclient-dev

> gem install mysql
```

source: http://heatware.net/ruby-rails/solved-installing-mysql-gem-extconf-rb-failed-error/

Comment: Any Idea what need to be dont for a mac for the same issue

Comment: You may want to check out this thread http://stackoverflow.com/a/6131858/834216. They suggest installing it using homebrew

Comment: Thank you for this! Worked on Ubuntu 12.04 and fixed my issue

Answer (score 2):

Just for the record: The problem should be solved!

The mysql2 gem v.0.2.6 is out, having win32 support.

`gem install mysql2` worked without problems now.

See: http://github.com/brianmario/mysql2/issues/issue/8#issue/8/comment/479748

Answer (score 2):

it works,
c:> **gem install mysql2 -- '--with-mysql-lib="C:\Prog
ram Files\MySQL\MySQL Connector C 6.0.2\lib\opt" --with-mysql-include="C:\Progra
m Files\MySQL\MySQL Connector C 6.0.2\include"'**

Temporarily enhancing PATH to include DevKit...

Building native extensions.  This could take a while...

Successfully installed mysql2-0.3.6

1 gem installed

Installing ri documentation for mysql2-0.3.6...

Enclosing class/module 'mMysql2' for class Client not known

Installing RDoc documentation for mysql2-0.3.6...

Enclosing class/module 'mMysql2' for class Client not known

**Note:**

I. If there is no lib and include directory in your mysql then **install mysql connector c**

II. First install **DevKit** then only you can install mysql2 plugin in windows
https://github.com/oneclick/rubyinstaller/wiki/Development-Kit

Answer (score 1):

You can try

```
gem install mysql2 -v '0.0.00' -- --with-ldflags=-L/usr/local/opt/openssl/lib --with-cppflags=-I/usr/local/opt/openssl/include
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you installed the DevKit correctly? If doubt, cross check the steps of installation on -
http://rorguide.blogspot.com/2011/03/installing-mysql2-gem-on-ruby-192-and.html

I was able to install mysql2 gem after following these steps.

Answer (score 0):

Under Cygwin, I had to be sure to install not just libmysqlclient18, but also libmysqlclient-devel. Then "gem install mysql2" went fine.

There is also, of course, a ruby-mysql2 package in Cygwin.

Answer (score -1):

key: the line that says You have to install development tools first.
ref: devkit

Comment: paste your output logs and make sure other gems install ok (like the "rdiscount" gem).  My guess is you wanted the mysql gem?

Answer (score -1):

use

```
gem install mysql
```

for windows, till mysql2 get it right.