# How do I install the mysql gem without a mysql server?

Tags: mysql, ruby, rubygems

I'm trying to install the mysql2 gem for a rails app on a machine with an external mysql server. The machine I'm installing onto doesn't have or need a mysql server on it. However, whenever I try to install it always checks for a mysql install and fails.
Is there an install configuration or work-around for this?

Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need just the MySQL header files to be there where the native compiling takes place.

Depending on your OS / Distribution you should find the way to install the header files without installing the actual server (Debian / Ubuntu alikes should allow you to do so with the standard apt-get, but I might be wrong).

If you are on Windows, please check this post about [mysql2 gem issues on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3655923/ruby-gem-mysql2-install-error).