# gem install mysql2 fails

Tags: mysql, ubuntu, rubygems

I got this error:

```
sudo gem install mysql2
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing mysql2:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

/usr/bin/ruby1.8 extconf.rb
checking for rb_thread_blocking_region()... no
checking for mysql.h... no
checking for mysql/mysql.h... no
-----
mysql.h is missing.  please check your installation of mysql and try again.
-----
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of
necessary libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more
details.  You may need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
    --with-opt-dir
    --without-opt-dir
    --with-opt-include
    --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
    --with-opt-lib
    --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
    --with-make-prog
    --without-make-prog
    --srcdir=.
    --curdir
    --ruby=/usr/bin/ruby1.8
    --with-mysql-config
    --without-mysql-config


Gem files will remain installed in /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/mysql2-0.2.6 for inspection.
Results logged to /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/mysql2-0.2.6/ext/mysql2/gem_make.out
```

I have tried:

- uninstall mysql2 and install it again
- uninstall mysql with apt-get
- installd dev-tools from mysql
- and almost all the pages on Google

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 94):

You need to install `libmysqlclient-dev` before installing the `mysql2` gem:

```
sudo apt-get install libmysqlclient-dev
gem install mysql2
```

This should fix this problem on the latest Ubuntu versions.

Comment: Worked for me on kali only my error was checking for mysql_query() in -lmysqlclient... no  Thanks.

Comment: If you have mariadb,then due to binary updation it might be unable to install `libmysqlclient-dev`. It would be good if we install `libmariadbclient-dev`,it will resolve both the issue.

Answer (score 9):

Thank Andre Schweighofer, just to it

```
sudo apt-get install libmysqlclient-dev
gem install mysql2

..
bundle update
bundle install
```

DONE !!!

Comment: If you are using MariaDB instead of MySQL install `libmariadbclient-dev`

Answer (score 3):

It require to install mysql development package

```
yum install mysql-devel
```

Answer (score 1):

Its helful to use the search here ;): [ruby-mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3608287/installing-mysql2-gem-for-rails-3)

here is another thread ;) with the same problem: [ruby-mysql2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3655923/ruby-gem-mysql2-install-error)

and many more when you search for "ruby mysql2" or something like this.

Comment: I tried most of the links and the are also for windows problems with mysql2. But i try it on a ubuntu. That's the strange thing!

Comment: Then you should read the articles a second time ;) there was an example how to install the package over apt-get try this.

Answer (score 1):

These are multiple causes of this failure :

1. Bad versions compatibility between ruby and rubygems
2. Missing libmysqlclient-dev
3. gem not locating the
4. Mysql 32bit on a 64 bit system

Solutions

1. Install rvm with latest stable release, You can switch after via rvm between ruby versions

> `curl -L https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable`

Install the dependecy

> `sudo apt-get install libmysqlclient-dev`

locate mysql_config on your system (find / -name mysql_config) and run

> `gem install mysql -- --with-mysql-config=/path/to/mysql_config`

Install the 64 bit version of mysql for your system

Answer (score 1):

It could be due to mysql updated binary ( In my case it was using Mariadb-10.0.31) and on installing the missing library( libmysqlclient-dev ), I got the following message that it would be impossible to resolve:

```
$ sudo apt-get install libmysqlclient-dev

Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libmysqlclient-dev : Depends: libmysqlclient18 (= 5.5.58-0ubuntu0.14.04.1)
```

But I resolved the above issue by first installing **libmariadbclient-dev** as:-

```
 $ sudo apt-get install libmariadbclient-dev
```

It will install **libmysqlclient-dev** as well but by first resolving mariadb dependency.

Answer (score 0):

On Ubuntu 10.10, I had to install libmysqlclient16-dev.

Answer (score 0):

The way I solved was to inspect the mkmf.log, which in my case was somewhere in 
./gems/ruby-2.2.3/extensions/x86_64-linux/2.2.0/mysql2-0.4.2/mkmf.log

In my case, there was an error that it could not find -lgmp, so it was missing the gmp library , so installed via apt-get , in this case libgmp-dev.