# How to use "mysql2" gem in Rails 3 application on Windows 7?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, windows-7, wamp, mysql2

I try to install the `mysql2` gem on Windows 7 32-bit.

I run:

```
gem install mysql2
```

and I get the following error:

```
ERROR:  Error installing mysql2:
        The 'mysql2' native gem requires installed build tools.

Please update your PATH to include build tools or download the DevKit
from 'http://rubyinstaller.org/downloads' and follow the instructions
at 'http://github.com/oneclick/rubyinstaller/wiki/Development-Kit'
```

Any ideas what could cause this error, and how to solve this ?

---

**UPDATE**

I did everything as described [here](http://rorguide.blogspot.com/2011/03/installing-mysql2-gem-on-ruby-192-and.html), but I can't figure out the last step:

```
gem install mysql2 -- 
     '--with-mysql-lib="c:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.1\lib\opt" 
      --with-mysql-include="c:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.1\include"'
```

I understand that I should change the paths to the correct paths in my system, but I can't find the `lib\opt` and the `include` directories in my WAMP MySQL installation. I use WAMP 2.1.

Please advise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try XAMPP from apachefriends.org, be sure to download the full version and you will find "lib", "bin", "include" and other MySQL directories. For further details, refer to -

http://rorguide.blogspot.com/2011/03/installing-mysql2-gem-on-ruby-192-and.html

Answer (score 25):

Here is a proper solution for anyone interested, that doesn't mess up your current installation of mysql server -

**EDIT : Make sure you download the right version on MySQL server. :**

if you intend to connect to a 6.0 or 5.5 server - download those binaries. I'm connecting to mysql 5.1 - hence my example. Also keep in mind latest mysql2 gem ( v 0.3.7) was tested against mysql server 6 - hence it keeps failing to build on windows for earlier versions. also make sure you use the right libmysql.dll in your ruby folder.

1. Download a zip file with mysql server 5.1 NOT the msi one. Make sure it's 32-bit NOT 64-bit. ([From here](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/mysql/5.1.html))
2. Since there is no installer file with this, create a folder c:\mysql-gem-install  - you can remove it once you finish.
3. Extract all the files from the zip file into the folder you just created.
4. now run this command

   ```
    gem install mysql2 --  '--with-mysql-lib="c:\mysql-gem-install\lib\opt"  --with-mysql-include="c:\mysql-gem-install\include"'
   ```

I just installed mysql2 gem v. 0.3.7

**EDIT 1**
One more thing: make sure you run the command in Command Prompt directly. As in not PowerShell or Consol2  - for some reason if you try that it will give you and error " invalid option" - has to do with the way -- is parsed.

**EDIT 2**
I just was doing a blank windows 7 install and one thing I ran into is that you need to add one more step to this: check to see if there is libmysql.dll in your ruby bin directory, if not copy one over from your mysql install. It should be of the same version as your mysql2 build.

Comment: Be careful when posting copy and paste boilerplate/verbatim answers to multiple questions, these tend to be flagged as "spammy" by the community.

Comment: Compiled but don't know how to include in GemFile

Comment: NM was using `bundle update` from the wrong file.  I know just to include it now.

Comment: @Kev - It's my answer - I just typed it up for one answer - and the pasted it for another one - that was pretty much the same question - but was coming up higher on google search result - this way more people will see it and avoid frustration - this mysql2 gem question is one of the most common ones for ruby on windows right now. My intention wasn't to spam :-)

Comment: Thanks for pointing out not to use PowerShell. I was getting invalid option all the time. Worked on standard cmd.

Comment: This is by far the best answer to this question and saved me a lot of time.  If you are using MySQL 5.5, use --with-mysql-lib="c:\mysql-gem-install\lib" since there is no opt directory in that install.  I used that to install version 0.3.14 of the mysql2 gem with no problems.

Answer (score 4):

THANK YOU!  One note:  I had to include the --platform=ruby option as well.  Thus, the final entire command line was:

`gem install mysql2 --platform=ruby -- '--with-mysql-lib="c:\mysql-gem-install\lib\opt" --with-mysql-include="c:\mysql-gem-install\include"'`

When I tried it without the platform=ruby option, DevKit didn't run and it just installed the normal mysql2 gem - it even gave a warning message about mysql2 being built for 6.0.2.  I uninstalled it (gem uninstall mysql2), then ran it again with --platform=ruby and it worked awesome!

Me:  Windows 7 64bit, Ruby 1.9.3p125, Rails 3.2.1, MySQL 5.1.56

Comment: FYI: The minute I did bundle update, bundler installs the existing mysql2 gem and starts using it in my app.  Here is the process for getting things to work again: 1) gem uninstall mysql2, select ALL.  2) run the gem install code again (my prev post, above). Done.

Comment: This did the trick for me. Another thing to note is to download the "no-install" zip file from the above link. For me it was "mysql-no-install-5.1.62-win32.zip".

Answer (score 2):

Well, i don't really use Windows, but what about downloading the DevKit from 'http://rubyinstaller.org/downloads' and following the instructions at 'http://github.com/oneclick/rubyinstaller/wiki/Development-Kit' ?

Comment: Previously, when I installed `mysql2` on Windows XP, I didn't have this problem. So I wonder whether the installation on Windows 7 should be so compicated. Is this a temporary woraround ?

Comment: That probably happened because you had the devkit installed on winxp beforehand. This one is essential for it to work. It's not a temporary solution, but something that you must do to have it work.

Comment: SpyrosP's answer will get you going. I recently used rubyinstaller & DevKit to get RoR 3 with Ruby 1.9.2 & MySql running without issue. Be sure to follow the devkit instructions religously.

Comment: @nathan: Have you used `mysql` or `mysql2` ?

Comment: @nathan: Moreover, I used the instructions and the installation test passed successfully!

Comment: @Misha mysql2. With DevKit environment variables are very important. Also, if you have other msys based programs like git, mingw, etc. they can interfere with DevKit's environment variables. Be sure when you drop to your command line you're using Devkit's binaries.

Comment: @nathan: I don't have things like git and mingw installed. What command did you use to install `mysql2` ? `gem install mysql2 <what is going here?>` What environment variables should I check ?

Comment: @nathan: Have you used WAMP's MySQL ?

Answer (score 0):

You should execute the setup file again,and choose the modify option,then check the Developer Components.When it finish,you will found the include folder and the opt folder.

Comment: I don't see any setup file in WAMP's installation directory. What do you mean by "setup file" ?

Answer (score 0):

Not all mysql2 versions come with windows binaries.

Easiest way to install gem mysql2 on windows is to pick a version that includes win binaries.

[Link to list of versions](http://rubygems.org/gems/mysql2/versions)

Choose the latest version number that includes “x86-mingw32”

For example 0.3.11

To install it:

```
gem install mysql2 -v 0.3.11
```

or in the gemfile:

```
gem „mysql2“, „0.3.11“
```