# many errors installing mysql on jruby

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, jruby

I'm trying to get mysql gem installed for use on rails, using jruby, can't figure this out...any help is appreciated!

```
$ sudo gem install mysql2

Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing mysql2:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

        /Users/masedesign/Work/repos/code/conf/vms/ruby/jruby/bin/jruby extconf.rb
WARNING: JRuby does not support native extensions or the `mkmf' library very well.
Check http://kenai.com/projects/jruby/pages/Home for alternatives.
checking for rb_thread_blocking_region()... checking for rb_wait_for_single_fd()... no
checking for mysql.h... yes
checking for errmsg.h... yes
checking for mysqld_error.h... yes
creating Makefile

make
cc -I. -I. -I/Users/masedesign/Work/repos/code/conf/vms/ruby/jruby/lib/native/include/ruby -I. -DHAVE_RB_THREAD_BLOCKING_REGION -DHAVE_MYSQL_H -DHAVE_ERRMSG_H -DHAVE_MYSQLD_ERROR_H  -D_XOPEN_SOURCE -D_DARWIN_C_SOURCE        -I/usr/local/mysql/include  -g -Os -arch x86_64 -fno-common   -D_P1003_1B_VISIBLE -DSIGNAL_WITH_VIO_CLOSE -DSIGNALS_DONT_BREAK_READ -DIGNORE_SIGHUP_SIGQUIT  -DDONT_DECLARE_CXA_PURE_VIRTUAL -fPIC -DTARGET_RT_MAC_CFM=0  -fno-omit-frame-pointer -fno-strict-aliasing  -fexceptions   -Wall -funroll-loops  -arch x86_64 -c client.c
cc -I. -I. -I/Users/masedesign/Work/repos/code/conf/vms/ruby/jruby/lib/native/include/ruby -I. -DHAVE_RB_THREAD_BLOCKING_REGION -DHAVE_MYSQL_H -DHAVE_ERRMSG_H -DHAVE_MYSQLD_ERROR_H  -D_XOPEN_SOURCE -D_DARWIN_C_SOURCE        -I/usr/local/mysql/include  -g -Os -arch x86_64 -fno-common   -D_P1003_1B_VISIBLE -DSIGNAL_WITH_VIO_CLOSE -DSIGNALS_DONT_BREAK_READ -DIGNORE_SIGHUP_SIGQUIT  -DDONT_DECLARE_CXA_PURE_VIRTUAL -fPIC -DTARGET_RT_MAC_CFM=0  -fno-omit-frame-pointer -fno-strict-aliasing  -fexceptions   -Wall -funroll-loops  -arch x86_64 -c mysql2_ext.c
cc -I. -I. -I/Users/masedesign/Work/repos/code/conf/vms/ruby/jruby/lib/native/include/ruby -I. -DHAVE_RB_THREAD_BLOCKING_REGION -DHAVE_MYSQL_H -DHAVE_ERRMSG_H -DHAVE_MYSQLD_ERROR_H  -D_XOPEN_SOURCE -D_DARWIN_C_SOURCE        -I/usr/local/mysql/include  -g -Os -arch x86_64 -fno-common   -D_P1003_1B_VISIBLE -DSIGNAL_WITH_VIO_CLOSE -DSIGNALS_DONT_BREAK_READ -DIGNORE_SIGHUP_SIGQUIT  -DDONT_DECLARE_CXA_PURE_VIRTUAL -fPIC -DTARGET_RT_MAC_CFM=0  -fno-omit-frame-pointer -fno-strict-aliasing  -fexceptions   -Wall -funroll-loops  -arch x86_64 -c result.c
cc -dynamic -bundle -undefined dynamic_lookup  -o mysql2.bundle client.o mysql2_ext.o result.o -L"." -L"/Users/masedesign/Work/repos/code/conf/vms/ruby/jruby-1.6.5/lib" -bundle -framework JavaVM -Wl,-syslibroot, -mmacosx-version-min=10.4  -Wl,-rpath,/usr/local/mysql/lib  -arch x86_64  -L/usr/local/mysql/lib -lmysqlclient_r -lz -lm     -lmygcc   
ld: library not found for -lbundle1.o
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make: *** [mysql2.bundle] Error 1


Gem files will remain installed in /Users/masedesign/Work/repos/code/conf/vms/ruby/jruby-1.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/mysql2-0.3.11 for inspection.
Results logged to /Users/masedesign/Work/repos/code/conf/vms/ruby/jruby-1.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/mysql2-0.3.11/ext/mysql2/gem_make.out
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `mysql` gem was developed and tested only against MRI (Ruby 1.8). As such it uses old-style C-extensions for most of their implementation. While they are technically supported by JRuby, they are slow and error-prone. So don't use them.

If you use JRuby, you are much better off of using the JDBC adapters which use the java-native database interface and are thus much faster and much better supported. The high-level interface (as e.g. used by Rails) is roughly the same, you shouldn't notice any difference.

So for JRuby you should use the `jdbc-mysql` gem, or - if you use Rails - the `activerecord-jdbcmysql-adapter` gem which requires that gem and adds the appropriate database adapter.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that this comes up from time to time. Here is an [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3655923/ruby-gem-mysql2-install-error) with some information (the second and third answers are more along what you are looking for).

On another note [this blog](http://www.digitalinsomniac.com/2011/04/07/testing-jruby-1-6/) suggests using `jdbc-mysql`.