# Jruby On Rails, which is best database adapter, mysql2 or jdbcmysql?

Tags: jruby, jrubyonrails

I am working on JRuby on Rails Application having **JRuby-1.6.7** and **Rails 3.2.2**

I have **mysql** database. I was trying for database adapter.

I used **mysql2** and **jdbcmysql** database adapter. Both are working.

But if I do not access application for some time and after that when I access it, it gives error as follows

```
undefined method `explain' for #<ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::MySQLAdapter:0x1139ba37>
```

Which database adapter I should prefer ? Will my aaplication work fine after deployment ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I got the same error before, but after some effort I have defined adapter's in my gem file as below, and things are working fine till today :

```
if defined?(JRUBY_VERSION)
  gem 'activerecord-jdbc-adapter', '=1.1.3'
  gem 'jdbc-mysql', :require=>false
  gem 'activerecord-jdbcmysql-adapter', '=1.1.3'
else
  gem 'mysql2'
end
```

hope that helps .

Comment: Thank you very much for your response.I have added the code in **GemFile** as per your suggestion.Now it is working fine.

Comment: Can you tell me what adapter I should declared in database.yml 
 adapter: mysql2 or adapter: jdbcmysql
Please let me know.

Comment: These can also just be written as gem 'activerecord-jdbc-adapter', '=1.1.3', :platforms => :jruby or gem 'mysql2', :platforms => :ruby

Answer (score 0):

I tried @Vik's solution of downgrading activerecord-jdbc, but it did not work for me - caused more problems.

I found this on the activerecord-jdbc github issues list:

https://github.com/jruby/activerecord-jdbc-adapter/issues/159

Basically it monkey-patches the new explain method to do nothing - until its extended to support it.

HTH, Chris

Comment: I still have some problem with it.Again got error "undefined method explain".I think jdbc-mysqladapter internally using mysql adapter from rails and mysql adapter do not have explain method but mysql2 adapter has.

Comment: Hi @shailesh_srk - have you tried the explain monkey patch mentioned in the github issue?  That provides an explain method, thus getting round the issue.

Comment: No, I have not tried it as patching is not good approach and it is patching in ActiveRecord. I am thinking to use mysql2 adapter instead of jdbcmysql in database.yml, what do you think ? Is there any other way ?

Comment: But your using JRuby, right?  I think that means your best bet is to use the jdbcmysql adaptor - the mysql2 is native and problematic with JRuby - see here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9865450/many-errors-installing-mysql-on-jruby.   The patch will be temporary until the gem is updated, its not like its core functionality.

Comment: Yes, you are right, using mysql2 with Jruby doesn't make sense.We should wait for the gem update.As Jruby is in process of building I hope they will get rid of "undefined method explain" error soon.I think this error is only for development, check development.rb in environments, 
`config.active_record.auto_explain_threshold_in_seconds = 0.5`
I think the error occurs when SQL query takes time more than 0.5.What say ?

Comment: Agreed - not a long term solution

Answer (score 0):

since AR-JDBC 1.2.x and esp. when using 1.3.x it's fine to keep the configuration **as is** for JRuby e.g. :

```
development:
  adapter: mysql2
  database: blog_development
  username: blog
production: 
  adapter: mysql2
  database: blog
  pool: 50
# ... etc
```

than in the **Gemfile** simply limit gems such as *mysql2* to MRI and *jdbc-mysql* to JRuby :

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '~> 3.2.17'

gem 'mysql2', :platform => :mri
gem 'activerecord-jdbc-adapter'
gem 'jdbc-mysql', :platform => :jruby

# ...
```

p.s. this q seems to be generating a lot of traffic for the repo, thus added an up-to-date answer.