# gitlab6.0, Error Connection refused - connect(2) (Errno::ECONNREFUSED)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, ssh, gitlab

### I installed gitlab

I installed gitlab, after reading

- https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/blob/master/doc/install/installation.md
- https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/blob/master/doc/install/databases.md
- [ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension (mysql2 on rails 3.2.3)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10051448/error-failed-to-build-gem-native-extension-mysql2-on-rails-3-2-3)
- http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2061057
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13018626/add-apt-repository-not-found

I make repository in gitlab on browser,
I set up `~/.ssh/config`,
and
`$ git push origin master`

### I got Erorr

```
/usr/local/lib/ruby/2.0.0/net/http.rb:878:in `initialize': Connection refused - connect(2) (Errno::ECONNREFUSED)
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.0.0/net/http.rb:878:in `open'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.0.0/net/http.rb:878:in `block in connect'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.0.0/timeout.rb:52:in `timeout'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.0.0/net/http.rb:877:in `connect'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.0.0/net/http.rb:862:in `do_start'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.0.0/net/http.rb:851:in `start'
    from /home/git/gitlab-shell/lib/gitlab_net.rb:62:in `get'
    from /home/git/gitlab-shell/lib/gitlab_net.rb:17:in `allowed?'
    from /home/git/gitlab-shell/lib/gitlab_shell.rb:60:in `validate_access'
    from /home/git/gitlab-shell/lib/gitlab_shell.rb:23:in `exec'
    from /home/git/gitlab-shell/bin/gitlab-shell:16:in `<main>'
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

### I have read them, but I can not resolve this error.

(Maybe I am poor English, so I miss reading)

- https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlab-shell/issues/20
- https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/issues/3384
- https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/issues/4566

### ssh -vT same Error

```
...
...
debug1: Sending env LC_CTYPE = UTF-8
debug1: Sending env LANG = ja_JP.UTF-8
/usr/local/lib/ruby/2.0.0/net/http.rb:878:in `initialize': Connection refused - connect(2) (Errno::ECONNREFUSED)
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.0.0/net/http.rb:878:in `open'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.0.0/net/http.rb:878:in `block in connect'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.0.0/timeout.rb:52:in `timeout'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.0.0/net/http.rb:877:in `connect'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.0.0/net/http.rb:862:in `do_start'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.0.0/net/http.rb:851:in `start'
    from /home/git/gitlab-shell/lib/gitlab_net.rb:62:in `get'
    from /home/git/gitlab-shell/lib/gitlab_net.rb:24:in `discover'
    from /home/git/gitlab-shell/lib/gitlab_shell.rb:77:in `user'
    from /home/git/gitlab-shell/lib/gitlab_shell.rb:82:in `username'
    from /home/git/gitlab-shell/lib/gitlab_shell.rb:36:in `exec'
    from /home/git/gitlab-shell/bin/gitlab-shell:16:in `<main>'
debug1: client_input_channel_req: channel 0 rtype exit-status reply 0
debug1: client_input_channel_req: channel 0 rtype eow@openssh.com reply 0
debug1: channel 0: free: client-session, nchannels 1
Transferred: sent 2560, received 3808 bytes, in 0.4 seconds
Bytes per second: sent 7260.5, received 10799.9
debug1: Exit status 1
```

### Why ssh useing Ruby?

Which setting use Ruby?
How to resolve this error?

### P.S.

I found which use ruby.

`/home/git/.ssh/authorized_keys`

```
command="/home/git/gitlab-shell/bin/gitlab-shell key-4",no-port-forwarding,no-X11-forwarding,no-agent-forwarding,no-pty ssh-rsa .....
```

so I command this

```
$ /home/git/gitlab-shell/bin/gitlab-shell key-4
```

I got same Error

```
usr/local/lib/ruby/2.0.0/net/http.rb:878:in `initialize': Connection refused - connect(2) (Errno::ECONNREFUSED)
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.0.0/net/http.rb:878:in `open'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.0.0/net/http.rb:878:in `block in connect'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.0.0/timeout.rb:52:in `timeout'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.0.0/net/http.rb:877:in `connect'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.0.0/net/http.rb:862:in `do_start'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.0.0/net/http.rb:851:in `start'
    from /home/git/gitlab-shell/lib/gitlab_net.rb:62:in `get'
    from /home/git/gitlab-shell/lib/gitlab_net.rb:24:in `discover'
    from /home/git/gitlab-shell/lib/gitlab_shell.rb:77:in `user'
    from /home/git/gitlab-shell/lib/gitlab_shell.rb:82:in `username'
    from /home/git/gitlab-shell/lib/gitlab_shell.rb:36:in `exec'
    from /home/git/gitlab-shell/bin/gitlab-shell:16:in `<main>'
```

So, I have read `/home/git/gitlab-shell/lib/gitlab_net.rb` script.

### gitlab_net.rb connect to

`gitlab_net.rb` connect to
`https://my-server/api/v3/internal/discover?key_id=5`
but I did not setup for https, so this is
`This webpage is not available`

`http://my-server/api/v3/internal/discover?key_id=5`
can connect to server.

I am so close.

setup ssl?

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem yesterday with my gitlab setup and was able to fix it after reading [this](https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlab-shell/issues/59). Basically what you do is to edit the `/etc/hosts` file on your 'my-server' computer and add

```
127.0.0.1  your-gitlab-url
```

Answer (score 1):

As I can see it can be little mistake in /home/git/gitlab-shell/config.yml 
something like:

gitlab_url: "http://gitlab.somedomain.com:8080/"

This address can be incorrect because gitlab-shell send request to Gitlab itself through http protocol and use this variable for connection.

Answer (score 0):

you probably should set:

```
gitlab_url: to http://localhost/
```

which is essential the same as:
    127.0.0.1  your-gitlab-url
otherwise: internal/discover etc. will receive 401

UPDATE:
please see:
https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/issues/4730#issuecomment-26332619
use

```
gitlab_url: to http://127.0.0.1
```

should work fine

Answer (score 0):

Check whether nginx is running properly.

`sudo nginx -t`

> Maybe there are problems like "a duplicate default server is detected"
>   and that default file is required to be removed.

After fixing the error(s), issue command

`sudo service nginx restart`

Rerun the check command under `/home/git/gitlab`

`sudo -u git -H bundle exec rake gitlab:check RAILS_ENV=production`