# Error installing mysql2 gem: Failed to build gem native extension

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

Windows XP. Ruby 1.9.2. Rails installed. MySQL installed. When I try to run `gem install mysql2` (or `bundle install`) I get errors:

```
C:\ruby\cred2>gem install mysql2
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing mysql2:
        ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

C:/Ruby192/bin/ruby.exe extconf.rb
checking for rb_thread_blocking_region()... *** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of
necessary libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more
details.  You may need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
        --with-opt-dir
        --without-opt-dir
        --with-opt-include
        --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
        --with-opt-lib
        --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
        --with-make-prog
        --without-make-prog
        --srcdir=.
        --curdir
        --ruby=C:/Ruby192/bin/ruby
C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:368:in `try_do': The complier failed to genera
te an executable file. (RuntimeError)
You have to install development tools first.
        from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:435:in `try_link0'
        from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:440:in `try_link'
        from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:552:in `try_func'
        from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:797:in `block in have_func'
        from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:693:in `block in checking_for'
        from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:280:in `block (2 levels) in postp
one'
        from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:254:in `open'
        from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:280:in `block in postpone'
        from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:254:in `open'
        from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:276:in `postpone'
        from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:692:in `checking_for'
        from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:796:in `have_func'
        from extconf.rb:9:in `<main>'


Gem files will remain installed in C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/mysql2-0.
2.4 for inspection.
Results logged to C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/mysql2-0.2.4/ext/mysql2/ge
m_make.out

C:\ruby\cred2>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Error installing mysql2: Failed to build gem native extension](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3608287/error-installing-mysql2-failed-to-build-gem-native-extension)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just for the record: The problem should be solved!

The mysql2 gem v.0.2.6 is out, having win32 support.

`gem install mysql2` worked without problems now (DevKit installed).

See: http://github.com/brianmario/mysql2/issues/issue/8#issue/8/comment/479748

Comment: Confirmed. No devkit required. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I guess that this gem uses C bindings and so has to be compiled. To do that in Windows you'd probably need to have the whole mingw (or possibly cygwin) environment set up. And still, [I'm not sure this will help](http://github.com/brianmario/mysql2/issues#issue/8).

You can try to use mysql or ruby-mysql on your Windows machine.

Answer (score 0):

if you haven't installed DevKit yet, this is the way to go.

I did it yesterday it worked perfectly (i have a Win XP box too).

the installation process is relatively straightforward (but well documented)

http://www.rubyinstaller.org/add-ons/devkit/