# MySQL Gem installation error on Rails

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, chef-infra

I am deploying my Rails application using Chef. While

> gem install mysql

am getting hte following error,

> Gem::Installer::ExtensionBuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native
>   extension.
>
> /opt/chef/embedded/bin/ruby extconf.rb  checking for
>   mysql_ssl_set()... *** extconf.rb failed *** Could not create Makefile
>   due to some reason, probably lack of necessary libraries and/or
>   headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may need
>   configuration options.
>
> Provided configuration options:   --with-opt-dir  --with-opt-include
>     --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include    --with-opt-lib
>     --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib    --with-make-prog
>     --without-make-prog     --srcdir=.  --curdir
>     --ruby=/opt/chef/embedded/bin/ruby  --with-mysql-config
>     --without-mysql-config
>   /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:381:in `try_do': The
>   compiler failed to generate an executable file. (RuntimeError) You
>   have to install development tools first.  from
>   /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:461:in`try_link0'  from
>   /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:476:in `try_link'   from
>   /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:619:in`try_func'   from
>   /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:894:in `block in have_func'
>     from /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:790:in`block in
>   checking_for'     from /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:284:in
>   `block (2 levels) in postpone'    from
>   /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:254:in`open'   from
>   /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:284:in `block in postpone'
>     from /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:254:in`open'    from
>   /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:280:in `postpone'   from
>   /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:789:in`checking_for'   from
>   /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:893:in `have_func'  from
>   extconf.rb:45:in`'
>
> Gem files will remain installed in
>   /var/www/project-name/releases/daf93f4783a7238e5a8198c1fd50e4e1de93f654/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/mysql-2.9.1
>   for inspection. Results logged to
>   /var/www/project-name/releases/daf93f4783a7238e5a8198c1fd50e4e1de93f654/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/mysql-2.9.1/ext/mysql_api/gem_make.out
>   An error occured while installing mysql (2.9.1), and Bundler cannot
>   continue. Make sure that `gem install mysql -v '2.9.1'` succeeds
>   before bundling.

I am using RHEL 6. I also have a separate cookbook for mysql installation. I tried installing Mysql manually using the yum command.

I tried

> yum install mysql-devel and then run the gem install mysql

still not working. Can anyone help me out.

Thanks

Comment: Maybe `yum install mysql mysql-server mysql-devel` ?

Comment: @MrYoshiji - i tried that and am getting the following error    
       Protected multilib versions: mysql-libs-5.1.69-1.el6_4.i686 != mysql-libs-5.5.33-1.el6.remi.x86_64
Error: Protected multilib versions: mysql-5.1.69-1.el6_4.i686 != mysql-5.5.33-1.el6.remi.x86_64
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
 You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest

Comment: `yum install mysql2` ? Seen here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3933829/error-installing-mysql2-gem-failed-to-build-gem-native-extension?rq=1

Comment: thats not working either

Comment: Oh I meant `gem install mysql2` and not with yum, also check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3608287/error-installing-mysql2-failed-to-build-gem-native-extension

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the [build-essentials](https://github.com/opscode-cookbooks/build-essential) cookbook to your runlist and configure it's "compiletime" attribute.

The following answer reports the same problem building the postgres gem

- [Issue with installing Postgres on Vagrant VM using Chef: undefined method `ruby' for Config:Module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18287581/issue-with-installing-postgres-on-vagrant-vm-using-chef-undefined-method-ruby/18288986#18288986)

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you don't have a compiler. On a debian/ubuntu system, you can get everything you need to compile and build packages with:

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential
```

On Fedora/Red Hat I think it should be:

```
sudo yum groupinstall "Development Tools"
```

Comment: I tried the sudo yum command and got the following error This system is not registered to Red Hat Subscription Management. You can use subscription-manager to register.
Setting up Group Process
epel/group_gz                                                                                                                                     | 237 kB     00:00     
No packages in any requested group available to install or update

Comment: Did you try to register? https://access.redhat.com/site/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Subscription_Management/1.0/html/Subscription_Management_Guide/registering-machine-ui.html

Comment: i got the Development tools working .. still the mysql gem throws the same error.