# A problem occurred when I update my gem!

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Installing mysql2 gem for Rails 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3608287/installing-mysql2-gem-for-rails-3)

I am a beginner with rails3,I had a problem when tried 'gem update' command.

Updating mysql2
ERROR: the "mysql2" native gem requires installed build tools.

Please update you PATH to include build tools or download the Devkit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you seen this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3608287/installing-mysql2-gem-for-rails-3)?

Comment: thanks,next time I will do some searching before I ask some stupid question such as this one.~_~