# create new application ruby on rails

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, rubygems, new-operator

I'm bit confused by "easy" working with ruby on rails, cause I already spend three days by trying create an app.

I work on site5 hosting, and try to create new app. step by step:

```
$ rails new app -d mysql

$ gem install mysql

$ gem install mysql2
```

and after

```
$ rake db:create
```

it report about error

`Could not find gem 'mysql2 (~> 0.2.6, runtime)' in any of the gem sources listed in your Gemfile.`

I google it, but still can't fix problem. Can anybody help?

Comment: When you run 'gem list' do you find the mysql gem in the list?

Comment: stocktra@stock.travel [~/public_html/ab.awithy.ru/app]# gem list mysql

*** REMOTE GEMS ***

mysql (2.8.1, 2.7.3)
mysql-inspector (0.0.6)
mysql-xml (0.1.1)
mysql2 (0.3.6, 0.2.6)
mysql2_bigint (0.2.6.1)
mysql2_model (0.1.2)
mysql2mysql (0.0.2)
mysql2psql (0.1.0)
mysql2xxxx (0.1.1)
mysql_backup (0.2.1)

Comment: does that mean, what I have mysql gem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Running `rails new app -d mysql` will automatically add the required gems to your Gemfile, so you shouldn't need to install them manually with the `gem` command. Try the following:

```
$ rails new app -d mysql
$ cd app
$ bundle install
$ rake db:create
```

I suspect the tutorial you're following is for an older version of Rails. With rails 3, you should be using [bundler](http://gembundler.com/) for all gem management.

Comment: yeah, thanks! problem was on my host, I should type $bundle install vendor/bundle

Answer (score 1):

This is how you do it.

```
gem list --local
```

Displays list of installed gems. Do you see mysql2 gem? If mysql2 is not installed run

```
gem install mysql2
```

You are now ready to launch a new rails app. Go to the desired directory and run

```
rails new my_app -d mysql
```

This will create a new rails app in directory my_app with mysql binding. Navigate to the app directory and run

```
rake about
```

If every thing is fine you should see the following

```
Database adapter         mysql2
```

Fire your favourite text editor and go to config/database.yml
Notice there are three databases, one each for development, test, and production. User will be "root" but without password. Enter the root password at all three places. You can also change user.

next open mysql and create three databases

```
mysql -u root -p
create database my_app_production;
create database my_app_test;
create database my_app_development;
exit
```

next in the terminal type

```
rails generate scaffold TableName name:string due:date etc...
rake db:migrate
```

...and you are done.
Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried running `gem install mysql2`?

If that is not working, try following [this tutorial](http://rorguide.blogspot.com/2011/03/installing-mysql2-gem-on-ruby-192-and.html)

It looks like your problems are generated by the missing mysql gem.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3608287/installing-mysql2-gem-for-rails-3) is another question regarding its installation. See if any of the solutions from there apply to you too

Comment: look above, I already tried $gem install mysql. also, I think this tutorial created for windows, but I need to make app on remote linux server

Comment: I edited my answer to give you another source of inspiration :)

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a similar problem. (I'm using rvm). I think I ran some code like:

The number after `libmysqlclient` may be different. And the path may be different for you too, but the concept should be similar.

> sudo install_name_tool -change
>   libmysqlclient.18.dylib
>   /usr/local/mysql/lib/libmysqlclient.18.dylib
>   ~/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p136\@rails3tutorial/gems/mysql2-0.2.7/lib/mysql2/mysql2.bundle