# How to install Nokogiri 1.6.7.2 on Windows

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, nokogiri

I read various pages on Stack Overflow but did't find a solution to install Nokogiri 1.6.7.2 with Ruby 2.3.0.

I installed Ruby 2.3.0 along with the DevKit, still I am unable to run `bundle install`. It always shows:

```
"An error occurred while installing nokogiri (1.6.7.2), and Bundler cannot
continue.
Make sure that `gem install nokogiri -v '1.6.7.2'` succeeds before bundling."
```

I ran the following devkit commands:

```
ruby dk.rb init
ruby dk.rb review
ruby dk.rb install
```

which ran successfully, and all Ruby versions show.

```
C:/Ruby200
C:/Ruby22
C:/Ruby23
```

I installed Ruby 2.2.4 also but when I run `bundle install` it shows:

```
ERROR:  Error installing nokogiri:
nokogiri requires Ruby version < 2.3, >= 1.9.2.
```

I am using Windows 7 32-bit system.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nokogiri 1.6.7.2 is not [the latest version](https://rubygems.org/gems/nokogiri/versions/1.6.7.2).

In your gemfile replace the "Nokogiri gem" line with this:

```
gem 'nokogiri', '~> 1.6.8.rc3'
```

In [Nokogiri issue #1456](https://github.com/sparklemotion/nokogiri/issues/1456) I found an possible solution.

First, uninstall all Nokogiri versions using `gem uninstall nokogiri`.

Run these commands in order:

```
gem install nokogiri -v '1.6.6.4'
gem install rails 
gem install nokogiri -v '1.6.8.rc3'
```

Then, open your Gemfile and add

```
gem 'nokogiri', '>=1.6.8.rc3'
```

Then run

```
bundle install
bundle update
```

This is the solution of user okeyparking, not mine. I recommend you to read the thread too.

Comment: 'gem install 'nokogiri', '~> 1.6.8.rc3' '

It show could not find a valid gem

Comment: I haven't added nokogiri in gemfile.

When I create a new project using

    rails _4.2.2_ new blog
Process certainly break down and show

**An error occurred while installing nokogiri (1.6.7.2), and Bundler cannot
continue.
Make sure that `gem install nokogiri -v '1.6.7.2'` succeeds before bundling.**

I don't know the reason. I have already installed:
**nokogiri (1.6.8.rc3 x86-mingw32, 1.6.6.2 x86-mingw32, 1.6.5 x86-mingw32, 1.5.5 x86-mingw32)**

Still getting issue when try to run bundle install while I haven't add this gem in the GemFile

Comment: I see.. In my machine, everything installs just fine. Try this: `bundle config build.nokogiri --use-system-libraries`

Comment: I have run:

`bundle config build.nokogiri --use-system-libraries`

Then run:

`bundle install`

Result:
`Gem::InstallError: nokogiri requires Ruby version < 2.3, >= 1.9.2.
Using rack-test 0.6.3
Using mime-types 3.1
Using binding_of_caller 0.7.2
Using coffee-script 2.4.1
Using uglifier 3.0.0
Using sprockets 3.6.0
Using sdoc 0.4.1
Using activesupport 4.2.2
Using tzinfo-data 1.2016.4
An error occurred while installing nokogiri (1.6.7.2), and Bundler cannot
continue.
Make sure that `gem install nokogiri -v '1.6.7.2'` succeeds before bundling.`

Comment: Still same error. I stuck with this from last 5 hours please help to fix this

Comment: @muditmehrotra I updated my answer, added an possible solution.

Comment: Thanks a lot @RareFever you saved my day. That solution worked now bundle installed and GemFile.lock file created successfully but when I run `rails server`

Now getting this error

`C:/Ruby23/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/sqlite3-1.3.11-x86-mingw32/lib/sqlite3.rb:6:in `require': cannot load such file -- sqlite3/sqlite3_native (LoadError)`

Now server not started :(

Comment: I am always happy to help ;) I would really apreciate if you marked the question as answered (+1 votes also helps ;) ). Your second issue is different, has nothing to do with nokogiri as you may already know. From my experience `sqlite3` does not work well in Windows, I recomend you very much to use **mysql2** gem, you could put into Gemfile this: `gem 'mysql2'`. Look [here for more info](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3585/create-a-new-ruby-on-rails-application-using-mysql-instead-of-sqlite) and [read this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6450466/create-new-application-ruby-on-rails)

Comment: Don't troll for your answer to be selected. It's considered bad form, especially when the question is only a few hours old. Instead, if an answer has obviously helped, and the OP hasn't selected an answer after a day or two, then it's considered helpful to them to add a comment under their question linking to http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers. We're here to help others, not to gather points.

Comment: @theTinMan As **mudit** said in his comment: “*you saved my day*”. That is pretty a good thing to hear. I will not troll any more. I just want peace. Thank you for the note.