# heroku db:pull cant connect to my DB in ubuntu

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ubuntu, heroku

So I recently updated ubuntu to 11.04 and then downgraded back to 11.04 because I hated unity. Anyway, after I reinstalled 11.40 I had to clone all my old heroku apps and tried to run `heroku db:pull` to pull the DB and have it imported into my mysql db but I keep getting this error:

```
Failed to connect to database:
  Sequel::AdapterNotFound -> LoadError: no such file to load -- mysql2
```

my gem file has `gem 'mysql2', '< 0.3'` and I gem installed taps already via RVM. I never had this issue when I ran db:pull before so I dont know what the problem is.

Im running ruby 1.9.2 with rails 3.0

Comment: which version of Rails do you use?

Comment: Have you verified you are using the correct values in your `database.yml` config file (Correct host [probably localhost], and a username/password that actually work to connect to your running instance of mysql)?

Comment: yeah, everything is right. I just started experiencing the problem after I upgraded to 11.10 and had to clone the app. I just downgraded back to 11.04 but Im still having the error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**run :**

`gem install mysql2` than `heroku db:pull` again ...

**if you get this error with the previous "gem install mysql2" :**

```
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing mysql2:
  ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.
```

**probably libmysqlclient-dev package should be installed :**

```
sudo apt-get install mysql-server mysql-server-5.1 libmysqlclient-dev mysql-client-5.1 mysql-common
```

**than**

```
gem install mysql2
```

**... or eventually run**

```
locate mysql_config
```

**then replace the resulting path, with in the following command path :**

```
sudo gem install mysql -- --with-mysql-config=/usr/local/mysql/bin/mysql_config
```

Answer (score 0):

You may have mysql2 in your `Gemfile` but have you done a `bundle install` - i.e. do you have the `mysql2` gem installed ?

Answer (score 0):

**run :**

> gem install taps then  heroku db:pull again

It may be work?