# Installing mysql2 gem for Ruby on Rails 3.1.0

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I get this error

> Gem files will remain installed in
>     /home/mark/.bundler/tmp/28288/gems/mysql2-0.2.17 for inspection.
>     Results logged to
>     /home/mark/.bundler/tmp/28288/gems/mysql2-0.2.17/ext/mysql2/gem_make.out
>     An error occured while installing mysql2 (0.2.17), and Bundler cannot
>     continue. Make sure that `gem install mysql2 -v '0.2.17'` succeeds
>     before bundling.

With a Ruby on Rails application and I can not solve it.

Comment: The cause of your problem is most probably in `/home/mark/.bundler/tmp/28288/gems/mysql2-0.2.17/ext/mysql2/gem_make.out`. And we can't help you wiothout knowing the contents of that file.

Comment: have you had a look at these pages,

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3608287/installing-mysql2-gem-for-rails-3

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8029832/heroku-dbpull-cant-connect-to-my-db-in-ubuntu

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7967648/facing-error-installing-mysql2-gem/8616459#8616459

Comment: It sounds like you haven't got MySQL installed on your machine.

Comment: What is the result of doing `gem install mysql2 -v '0.2.17'` ?

Answer (score 24):

Most folks find this works:

```
sudo apt-get install libmysql-ruby libmysqlclient-dev
```

Answer (score 0):

It's probably a compilation error. Maybe you don't have mysql development libs installed in your system.

I need to see the logs to make sure. 
Try it and paste the output here:

```
cat /home/mark/.bundler/tmp/28288/gems/mysql2-0.2.17/ext/mysql2/gem_make.out
```

Btw: wich operation system are you using?