# Rails error while installing fcgi: Failed to build gem native extension

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I was running the command

```
bundle install
```

on my Rails project, and it gave the error:

```
...
Using activerecord (3.0.11) 
Using activeresource (3.0.11) 
Using bigdecimal (1.1.0) 
Installing fcgi (0.8.8) with native extensions 
Gem::Installer::ExtensionBuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    /home/jjboat/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/bin/ruby extconf.rb 
checking for fcgiapp.h... no
checking for fastcgi/fcgiapp.h... no
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of
necessary libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more
details.  You may need configuration options.
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You need to install the fcgi development package to be able to build native extensions (and you have to have install a C build chain before that as well). You haven't specified your distro here, but on Red Hat (and derivatives like Fedora) you'll generally do it like this:

```
sudo yum install fcgi-devel
```

and on Debian (and Ubuntu) you can do the same like this:

```
sudo apt-get install libfcgi-dev
```

I'm not 100% certain about the name of the package in Debian, but it should be easy for you to figure it out.

Comment: I'm using Ubuntu 10.04, and it says:

sudo apt-get install fcgi-dev
[sudo] password for jjboat: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Couldn't find package fcgi-dev

Comment: It seems that the package is actually called `libfcgi-dev` in Ubuntu.

Comment: Thanks, `libfcgi-dev` is correct. Now it hits an error for `mysql2`. Do you know what package should be installed?

An error occurred while installing mysql2 (0.2.17), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install mysql2 -v '0.2.17'` succeeds before bundling.

Comment: Well never mind, got it here :)

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8874513/installing-mysql2-gem-for-ruby-on-rails-3-1-0

Answer (score 8):

If you hit this same error with the fcgi gem on MacOS X (tested on 10.7.5). You can get the development packages required using homebrew ([Link](https://brew.sh)):

```
brew install fcgi
```

Then you should be all set to install the gem:

```
gem install fcgi -v '0.8.8'
```