# Installing mysql gem for ruby

Tags: mysql, ruby, ubuntu, rubygems, installation

I have trouble installing the mysql gem:

```
gem install mysql

Fetching: mysql-2.8.1.gem (100%)
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing mysql:
ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    /home/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/bin/ruby extconf.rb
checking for mysql_query() in -lmysqlclient... no
checking for main() in -lm... yes
checking for mysql_query() in -lmysqlclient... no
checking for main() in -lz... yes
checking for mysql_query() in -lmysqlclient... no
checking for main() in -lsocket... no
checking for mysql_query() in -lmysqlclient... no
checking for main() in -lnsl... yes
checking for mysql_query() in -lmysqlclient... no
checking for main() in -lmygcc... no
checking for mysql_query() in -lmysqlclient... no
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of
necessary libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more
details.  You may need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
--with-opt-dir
--without-opt-dir
--with-opt-include
--without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
--with-opt-lib
--without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
--with-make-prog
--without-make-prog
--srcdir=.
--curdir
--ruby=/home/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/bin/ruby
--with-mysql-config
--without-mysql-config
--with-mysql-dir
--without-mysql-dir
--with-mysql-include
--without-mysql-include=${mysql-dir}/include
--with-mysql-lib
--without-mysql-lib=${mysql-dir}/lib
--with-mysqlclientlib
--without-mysqlclientlib
--with-mlib
--without-mlib
--with-mysqlclientlib
--without-mysqlclientlib
--with-zlib
--without-zlib
--with-mysqlclientlib
--without-mysqlclientlib
--with-socketlib
--without-socketlib
--with-mysqlclientlib
--without-mysqlclientlib
--with-nsllib
--without-nsllib
--with-mysqlclientlib
--without-mysqlclientlib
--with-mygcclib
--without-mygcclib
--with-mysqlclientlib
--without-mysqlclientlib
```

the mkmf.log file consists of heaps of gcc debug output that is of no help to me, I can post it but I bet it's more trivial like the mentioned configuration options.

Has anyone got experience with this on a Ubuntu1104 system?

Thankful for any hints!

Cheers,
Mac

Comment: possible duplicate of [Installing mysql2 gem for Rails 3](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3608287/installing-mysql2-gem-for-rails-3)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently you haven't installed MySQL development libraries necessary to compile this gem. [libmysqlclient-dev](http://packages.ubuntu.com/lucid/libmysqlclient-dev) might help.

Comment: at least one question a day regarding this issue?