# I want to upgrade from mysql to mysql2 on Joyent

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, mysql2, joyent

I got following error in my Application.

```
incompatible character encodings: ASCII-8BIT and UTF-8
```

I found solution for this for which i need to upgrade mysql gem to mysql2 in remote server i.e. JOYENT.

When i run `"gem install mysql2"` i got following error

```
Error installing mysql2: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.
```

Now i want to know how can i install `mysql2` on server?

I tried following

```
sudo apt-get install libmysql-ruby libmysqlclient-dev
```

Ref:- [Error installing mysql2: Failed to build gem native extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3608287/installing-mysql2-gem-for-rails-3)

but when i run above command it gives me following error

```
/bin/sh: apt-get: not found
```

Now i want to know what steps i should follow so that i able to install `mysql2`

Answer (score 1):

Following command works for me

```
gem install mysql2 -v 0.2.6
```

In gemfile

```
gem 'mysql2', '0.2.6'
```

In database.yml file

```
production:
  adapter: mysql2
```

Ref link:- http://discuss.joyent.com/viewtopic.php?id=29266