# rail servers error? (rails 3) in windows

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, database, ruby-on-rails-3

I created a new project using the command:

> rails new simple_cms -d mysql

but when I try to launch the web server, this happens:

```
C:\Users\johnny\Sites\simple_cms>rails server
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/mysql2-0.3.11-x86-mingw32/lib/mysql2/mysql2.rb:2:in `require': 193: %1 is not a valid Win32 application.   - C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/mysql2-0.3.11-x86-mingw32/lib/mysql2/1.9/mysql2.so (LoadError)
    from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/mysql2-0.3.11-x86-mingw32/lib/mysql2/mysql2.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
    from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/mysql2-0.3.11-x86-mingw32/lib/mysql2.rb:9:in `require'
    from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/mysql2-0.3.11-x86-mingw32/lib/mysql2.rb:9:in `<top (required)>'
    from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.1.1/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:68:in `require'
    from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.1.1/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:68:in `block (2 levels) in require'
    from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.1.1/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:66:in `each'
    from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.1.1/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:66:in `block in require'
    from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.1.1/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:55:in `each'
    from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.1.1/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:55:in `require'
    from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.1.1/lib/bundler.rb:119:in `require'
    from C:/Users/johnny/Sites/simple_cms/config/application.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
    from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.2/lib/rails/commands.rb:53:in `require'
    from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.2/lib/rails/commands.rb:53:in `block in <top (required)>'
    from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.2/lib/rails/commands.rb:50:in `tap'
    from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.2/lib/rails/commands.rb:50:in `<top (required)>'
    from script/rails:6:in `require'
    from script/rails:6:in `<main>'

C:\Users\johnny\Sites\simple_cms>
```

Some version info just in case:

```
C:\Users\j\Sites\simple_cms>ruby -v
ruby 1.9.3p125 (2012-02-16) [i386-mingw32]

C:\Users\j\Sites\simple_cms>ruby -v
ruby 1.9.3p125 (2012-02-16) [i386-mingw32]

C:\Users\j\Sites\simple_cms>mysql --version
mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.5.21, for Win64 (x86)
```

I've already searched the web looking for solutions, but none of them
seem to work. Any help would be greatly appreciated, thank you.

Comment: To format the output, edit your post and add four spaces in front of each line of output you would like to remain unmolested.  It might also be possible to select the lines and use the curly-braces button on the editor.

Comment: I formatted it, but I still havent figured out what's wrong with "rails server"

Comment: is your MySQL/bin there in your PATH variable?

Comment: @uDay yea i think so, when I type "mysql --version" from any directory it gives me "mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.5.21, for Win64 (x86)" but when I use "mysql <insert anyhting besides --version>" it gives me "ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'ODBC'@'localhost' (using password: NO)"

Comment: it says you dont have the password for the root user

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the .dll file required to run mysql2 is not available, and, as a result, it does not recognize it as a valid Win32 application.

Download the "mysql-connector-c-noinstall-6.0.2" from [the official repository](http://www.mysql.com/downloads/mirror.php?id=377978).  You may be asked to register, but it's free. Go to downloads, select "MySQL Connectors => Connector/C (libmysql)".

Unzip the downloaded file, then copy "libmysql.dll", located in the lib folder, to your Ruby/bin folder.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issues once with my server on mac. I changed the version of ruby and it helped. Change the version of ruby to 1.8.7 and try if it works.

Comment: Hey, do I have to gem install rails for every version of ruby i have installed? I'm using pik to switch between ruby versions. When I switched to 1.8.7, the rails command stopped working "'rails' is not recognized as an internal or external..."

Comment: Take a look at the answers for this Question:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3608287/installing-mysql2-gem-for-rails-3