# rails server command not working on windows 8

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am doing Ruby on Rails Essential Training From Lynda.com and whille typing the command 'rails server' on windows command prompt, the server stops on its own and shows the following line at the end

```
from bin/rails:4:in `require'
from bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
```

Following are my commands

```
rails new local_host -d mysql
cd C:\Users\KSHITIJ\Documents\Rails\local_host
rails server
```

The first two commands works just fine but the third one doesnt
Please Help Thanks

Comment: It is possible for you to learn ruby on rails using windows. But based on my experience. Currently, develop rails app in windows is alot of pain. I suggest you to using vagrant or make your pc dual boot with linux.

Comment: It requires a lot of information about your host machine. I ran Rails server on Windows Server 2012 R2: it's **awfully slow** (because that was MRI, not JRuby), but it works. Really, consider using a virtual machine. When coupled with shared folders, development workflow becomes much easier and faster, provided that your CPU supports virtualization well enough.

Answer (score 0):

We can hardly offer suggestion with little information like this. Please provide full message which will help us inspect the problem. Paste the full message [like he did in this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9779998/rail-servers-error-rails-3-in-windows). Thanks!

Comment: Asking for information is preferable with a comment to the question. It's how StackOverflow works.