# Rails4, Ruby2, MySLQ2 and RubyMine

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, macos

I'm getting this same error message as all of you, but I'm on a Mac (10.8), using Rails4 and Ruby2 and RubyMine (IDE).

```
/Users/eric/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p195/bin/ruby -e $stdout.sync=true;$stderr.sync=true;load($0=ARGV.shift) /Users/eric/Rubymine/Chroma/bin/bundle install
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/........
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/..
Resolving dependencies...
...
...
...
Installing mysql2 (0.3.11) 
Gem::Installer::ExtensionBuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

/Users/eric/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p195/bin/ruby extconf.rb 
checking for rb_thread_blocking_region()... yes
checking for rb_wait_for_single_fd()... yes
checking for mysql_query() in -lmysqlclient... no
checking for main() in -lm... yes
checking for mysql_query() in -lmysqlclient... no
checking for main() in -lz... yes
checking for mysql_query() in -lmysqlclient... no
checking for main() in -lsocket... no
checking for mysql_query() in -lmysqlclient... no
checking for main() in -lnsl... no
checking for mysql_query() in -lmysqlclient... no
checking for main() in -lmygcc... no
checking for mysql_query() in -lmysqlclient... no
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
--with-opt-dir
--with-opt-include
--without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
--with-opt-lib
--without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
--with-make-prog
--without-make-prog
--srcdir=.
--curdir
--ruby=/Users/eric/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p195/bin/ruby
--with-mysql-config
--without-mysql-config
--with-mysql-dir
--without-mysql-dir
--with-mysql-include
--without-mysql-include=${mysql-dir}/include
--with-mysql-lib
--without-mysql-lib=${mysql-dir}/
--with-mysqlclientlib
--without-mysqlclientlib
--with-mlib
--without-mlib
--with-mysqlclientlib
--without-mysqlclientlib
--with-zlib
--without-zlib
--with-mysqlclientlib
--without-mysqlclientlib
--with-socketlib
--without-socketlib
--with-mysqlclientlib
--without-mysqlclientlib
--with-nsllib
--without-nsllib
--with-mysqlclientlib
--without-mysqlclientlib
--with-mygcclib
--without-mygcclib
--with-mysqlclientlib
--without-mysqlclientlib

Gem files will remain installed in /Users/eric/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195@global/gems/mysql2-0.3.11 for inspection.
Results logged to /Users/eric/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195@global/gems/mysql2-0.3.11/ext/mysql2/gem_make.out
An error occurred while installing mysql2 (0.3.11), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install mysql2 -v '0.3.11'` succeeds before bundling.

Process finished with exit code 5
```

I have tried a number of other things from around the web as well:
- Running `gem install mysql2` from the command line gets me the same message as above.
- Running `gem 'mysql2'` gets me this error: `ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::CommandLineError) Unknown command mysql2` even though I have it it my Gemfile: http://d.pr/n/jc3i
- I have tried adding `rvm install libmysql-ruby` hoping that would fix it.. nope..

I should mention this is my first real foray into RoR, so it's quite possible *I'm* the problem... I've looked all over StackOverflow and haven't really had any luck there either. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: check this out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3608287/installing-mysql2-gem-for-rails-3

Answer (score 0):

I used to run into this problem all the time. Have you tried installing the gem against the MySQL install:

```
env ARCHFLAGS="-arch x86_64" gem install mysql2 -- --with-mysql-dir=/usr/local/mysql
```

(note the double double dashes… they are intended)

Of course your MySQL installation might be somewhere else, so adjust accordingly.

I also remember having to relink the libmysqlclient.18.dylib but that may not be necessary anymore. For reference, it went like so:

```
sudo install_name_tool -change libmysqlclient.18.dylib /usr/local/mysql/lib/libmysqlclient.18.dylib /Users/levifig/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/mysql2-0.3.11/lib/mysql2/mysql2.bundle
```

Hope this gets you in the right direction. If not, I'll try to help anyway… :)