# Rails installing mysql - Error installing mysql2: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, sqlite, deployment

I have a `Rails 3.2.13` app that I would like deployed, but the hosting service would require MySQL, as opposed to sqlite which I have been using.

In the process of converting from `sqlite` to `MySQL`, I had to install the ruby gem `mysql2`, which is giving me the following error upon installing:

> Error installing mysql2: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

I've tried both `bundle install`, as well as `gem install mysql2`, but the same error message appeared.

I am aware that the solution that has worked for many is `sudo apt-get install libmysql-ruby libmysqlclient-dev`, but I'm using Git Bash on **Windows**, so I found a Windows equivalent (@francois's answer on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3608287/error-installing-mysql2-failed-to-build-gem-native-extension)). I installed `MySQL Server 5.6` with the installer, and ran the following command:

```
gem install mysql2 -- '--with-mysql-lib="c:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6\lib" --with-mysql-include="c:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6\include"'
```

From what I have read, this is supposed to successfully install the 'mysql2' ruby gem.  But strangely enough, I still had the following error:

> ```
>     Temporarily enhancing PATH to include DevKit... Building native extensions with: '--with-mysql-lib="c:\Program
> ```
>
> Files\MySQL\MySQL  Server 5.6\lib" --with-mysql-include="c:\Program
>   Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6\i nclude"' This could take a while...
>   ERROR:  Error installing mysql2:
>                   ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.
>
> ```
>         c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/bin/ruby.exe extconf.rb --with-mysql-lib="c:\Pro gram Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6\lib" --with-mysql-include="c:\Program Files\My SQL\MySQL Server 5.6\include" checking for rb_thread_blocking_region()... yes checking for rb_wait_for_single_fd()... yes checking for rb_hash_dup()... yes
> ```
>
> checking for rb_intern3()... yes checking for main() in -llibmysql...
>   yes checking for mysql.h... yes checking for errmsg.h... yes checking
>   for mysqld_error.h... yes creating Makefile
>
> ```
>     make generating mysql2-i386-mingw32.def compiling client.c client.c: In function 'rb_raise_mysql2_error': client.c:139:3:
> ```
>
> warning: ISO C90 forbids mixed declarations and code client.c: In
>   function 'finish_and_mark_inactive': client.c:508:3: warning: ISO C90
>   forbids mixed declarations and code client.c: In function
>   'rb_mysql_client_abandon_results': client.c:535:3: warning: ISO C90
>   forbids mixed declarations and code client.c: In function
>   'rb_mysql_client_next_result': client.c:938:5: warning: ISO C90
>   forbids mixed declarations and code compiling mysql2_ext.c compiling
>   result.c result.c: In function 'rb_mysql_result_fetch_fields':
>   result.c:407:35: warning: comparison between signed and unsigned
>   integer express ions linking shared-object mysql2/mysql2.so client.o:
>   In function `nogvl_connect':
>   c:\RailsInstaller\Ruby1.9.3\lib\ruby\gems\1.9.1\gems\mysql2-0.3.13\ext\mysql2/cl
>   ient.c:158: undefined reference to`mysql_real_connect@32' client.o:
>   In function `nogvl_init':
>   c:\RailsInstaller\Ruby1.9.3\lib\ruby\gems\1.9.1\gems\mysql2-0.3.13\ext\mysql2/cl
>   ient.c:150: undefined reference to`mysql_init@4' client.o: In
>   function `set_ssl_options':
>   c:\RailsInstaller\Ruby1.9.3\lib\ruby\gems\1.9.1\gems\mysql2-0.3.13\ext\mysql2/cl
>   ient.c:1078: undefined reference to`mysql_ssl_set@24' client.o: In
>   function `mysql_client_options':
>   c:\RailsInstaller\Ruby1.9.3\lib\ruby\gems\1.9.1\gems\mysql2-0.3.13\ext\mysql2/cl
>   ient.c:723: undefined reference to`mysql_options@12'
>   c:\RailsInstaller\Ruby1.9.3\lib\ruby\gems\1.9.1\gems\mysql2-0.3.13\ext\mysql2/cl
>   ient.c:727: undefined reference to `mysql_error@4' client.o: In
>   function`rb_mysql_info':
>   c:\RailsInstaller\Ruby1.9.3\lib\ruby\gems\1.9.1\gems\mysql2-0.3.13\ext\mysql2/cl
>   ient.c:267: undefined reference to `mysql_info@4' client.o: In
>   function`rb_mysql_client_warning_count':
>   c:\RailsInstaller\Ruby1.9.3\lib\ruby\gems\1.9.1\gems\mysql2-0.3.13\ext\mysql2/cl
>   ient.c:257: undefined reference to `mysql_warning_count@4' client.o:
>   In function`nogvl_do_result':
>   c:\RailsInstaller\Ruby1.9.3\lib\ruby\gems\1.9.1\gems\mysql2-0.3.13\ext\mysql2/cl
>   ient.c:370: undefined reference to `mysql_store_result@4' client.o: In
>   function`rb_mysql_client_more_results':
>   c:\RailsInstaller\Ruby1.9.3\lib\ruby\gems\1.9.1\gems\mysql2-0.3.13\ext\mysql2/cl
>   ient.c:923: undefined reference to `mysql_more_results@4' client.o: In
>   function`nogvl_select_db':
>   c:\RailsInstaller\Ruby1.9.3\lib\ruby\gems\1.9.1\gems\mysql2-0.3.13\ext\mysql2/cl
>   ient.c:863: undefined reference to `mysql_select_db@8' client.o: In
>   function`nogvl_ping':
>   c:\RailsInstaller\Ruby1.9.3\lib\ruby\gems\1.9.1\gems\mysql2-0.3.13\ext\mysql2/cl
>   ient.c:894: undefined reference to `mysql_ping@4' client.o: In
>   function`rb_mysql_client_thread_id':
>   c:\RailsInstaller\Ruby1.9.3\lib\ruby\gems\1.9.1\gems\mysql2-0.3.13\ext\mysql2/cl
>   ient.c:856: undefined reference to `mysql_thread_id@4' client.o: In
>   function`rb_mysql_client_last_id':
>   c:\RailsInstaller\Ruby1.9.3\lib\ruby\gems\1.9.1\gems\mysql2-0.3.13\ext\mysql2/cl
>   ient.c:825: undefined reference to `mysql_insert_id@4' client.o: In
>   function`nogvl_read_query_result':
>   c:\RailsInstaller\Ruby1.9.3\lib\ruby\gems\1.9.1\gems\mysql2-0.3.13\ext\mysql2/cl
>   ient.c:357: undefined reference to `mysql_read_query_result@4'
>   client.o: In function`rb_mysql_client_server_info':
>   c:\RailsInstaller\Ruby1.9.3\lib\ruby\gems\1.9.1\gems\mysql2-0.3.13\ext\mysql2/cl
>   ient.c:788: undefined reference to `mysql_get_server_version@4'
>   c:\RailsInstaller\Ruby1.9.3\lib\ruby\gems\1.9.1\gems\mysql2-0.3.13\ext\mysql2/cl
>   ient.c:789: undefined reference to`mysql_get_server_info@4' client.o:
>   In function `rb_mysql_client_info':
>   c:\RailsInstaller\Ruby1.9.3\lib\ruby\gems\1.9.1\gems\mysql2-0.3.13\ext\mysql2/cl
>   ient.c:756: undefined reference to`mysql_get_client_version@0'
>   c:\RailsInstaller\Ruby1.9.3\lib\ruby\gems\1.9.1\gems\mysql2-0.3.13\ext\mysql2/cl
>   ient.c:757: undefined reference to `mysql_get_client_info@0' client.o:
>   In function`rb_mysql_client_real_escape':
>   c:\RailsInstaller\Ruby1.9.3\lib\ruby\gems\1.9.1\gems\mysql2-0.3.13\ext\mysql2/cl
>   ient.c:662: undefined reference to `mysql_real_escape_string@16'
>   client.o: In function`finish_and_mark_inactive':
>   c:\RailsInstaller\Ruby1.9.3\lib\ruby\gems\1.9.1\gems\mysql2-0.3.13\ext\mysql2/cl
>   ient.c:515: undefined reference to `mysql_free_result@4' client.o: In
>   function`nogvl_send_query':
>   c:\RailsInstaller\Ruby1.9.3\lib\ruby\gems\1.9.1\gems\mysql2-0.3.13\ext\mysql2/cl
>   ient.c:334: undefined reference to `mysql_send_query@12' client.o: In
>   function`nogvl_close':
>   c:\RailsInstaller\Ruby1.9.3\lib\ruby\gems\1.9.1\gems\mysql2-0.3.13\ext\mysql2/cl
>   ient.c:190: undefined reference to `mysql_close@4' client.o: In
>   function`rb_mysql_client_escape':
>   c:\RailsInstaller\Ruby1.9.3\lib\ruby\gems\1.9.1\gems\mysql2-0.3.13\ext\mysql2/cl
>   ient.c:238: undefined reference to `mysql_escape_string@12' client.o:
>   In function`rb_raise_mysql2_error':
>   c:\RailsInstaller\Ruby1.9.3\lib\ruby\gems\1.9.1\gems\mysql2-0.3.13\ext\mysql2/cl
>   ient.c:125: undefined reference to `mysql_error@4'
>   c:\RailsInstaller\Ruby1.9.3\lib\ruby\gems\1.9.1\gems\mysql2-0.3.13\ext\mysql2/cl
>   ient.c:126: undefined reference to`mysql_sqlstate@4'
>   c:\RailsInstaller\Ruby1.9.3\lib\ruby\gems\1.9.1\gems\mysql2-0.3.13\ext\mysql2/cl
>   ient.c:140: undefined reference to `mysql_errno@4' client.o: In
>   function`rb_connect':
>   c:\RailsInstaller\Ruby1.9.3\lib\ruby\gems\1.9.1\gems\mysql2-0.3.13\ext\mysql2/cl
>   ient.c:297: undefined reference to `mysql_errno@4' client.o: In
>   function`rb_mysql_client_store_result':
>   c:\RailsInstaller\Ruby1.9.3\lib\ruby\gems\1.9.1\gems\mysql2-0.3.13\ext\mysql2/cl
>   ient.c:966: undefined reference to `mysql_errno@4' client.o: In
>   function`rb_mysql_client_next_result':
>   c:\RailsInstaller\Ruby1.9.3\lib\ruby\gems\1.9.1\gems\mysql2-0.3.13\ext\mysql2/cl
>   ient.c:939: undefined reference to `mysql_next_result@4' client.o: In
>   function`rb_mysql_client_affected_rows':
>   c:\RailsInstaller\Ruby1.9.3\lib\ruby\gems\1.9.1\gems\mysql2-0.3.13\ext\mysql2/cl
>   ient.c:839: undefined reference to `mysql_affected_rows@4' client.o:
>   In function`rb_mysql_client_async_result':
>   c:\RailsInstaller\Ruby1.9.3\lib\ruby\gems\1.9.1\gems\mysql2-0.3.13\ext\mysql2/cl
>   ient.c:419: undefined reference to `mysql_errno@4' client.o: In
>   function`rb_mysql_client_abandon_results':
>   c:\RailsInstaller\Ruby1.9.3\lib\ruby\gems\1.9.1\gems\mysql2-0.3.13\ext\mysql2/cl
>   ient.c:539: undefined reference to `mysql_next_result@4'
>   c:\RailsInstaller\Ruby1.9.3\lib\ruby\gems\1.9.1\gems\mysql2-0.3.13\ext\mysql2/cl
>   ient.c:538: undefined reference to`mysql_more_results@4'
>   c:\RailsInstaller\Ruby1.9.3\lib\ruby\gems\1.9.1\gems\mysql2-0.3.13\ext\mysql2/cl
>   ient.c:547: undefined reference to `mysql_free_result@4' client.o: In
>   function`nogvl_do_result':
>   c:\RailsInstaller\Ruby1.9.3\lib\ruby\gems\1.9.1\gems\mysql2-0.3.13\ext\mysql2/cl
>   ient.c:368: undefined reference to `mysql_use_result@4' client.o: In
>   function`nogvl_close':
>   c:\RailsInstaller\Ruby1.9.3\lib\ruby\gems\1.9.1\gems\mysql2-0.3.13\ext\mysql2/cl
>   ient.c:190: undefined reference to `mysql_close@4' client.o: In
>   function`set_charset_name':
>   c:\RailsInstaller\Ruby1.9.3\lib\ruby\gems\1.9.1\gems\mysql2-0.3.13\ext\mysql2/cl
>   ient.c:1067: undefined reference to `mysql_options@12'
>   c:\RailsInstaller\Ruby1.9.3\lib\ruby\gems\1.9.1\gems\mysql2-0.3.13\ext\mysql2/cl
>   ient.c:1069: undefined reference to`mysql_error@4' client.o: In
>   function `init_mysql2_client':
>   c:\RailsInstaller\Ruby1.9.3\lib\ruby\gems\1.9.1\gems\mysql2-0.3.13\ext\mysql2/cl
>   ient.c:1105: undefined reference to`mysql_get_client_info@0'
>   result.o: In function `rb_mysql_result_count':
>   c:\RailsInstaller\Ruby1.9.3\lib\ruby\gems\1.9.1\gems\mysql2-0.3.13\ext\mysql2/re
>   sult.c:576: undefined reference to`mysql_num_rows@4' result.o: In
>   function `rb_mysql_result_fetch_field':
>   c:\RailsInstaller\Ruby1.9.3\lib\ruby\gems\1.9.1\gems\mysql2-0.3.13\ext\mysql2/re
>   sult.c:126: undefined reference to`mysql_fetch_field_direct@8'
>   c:\RailsInstaller\Ruby1.9.3\lib\ruby\gems\1.9.1\gems\mysql2-0.3.13\ext\mysql2/re
>   sult.c:114: undefined reference to `mysql_num_fields@4' result.o: In
>   function`rb_mysql_result_fetch_fields':
>   c:\RailsInstaller\Ruby1.9.3\lib\ruby\gems\1.9.1\gems\mysql2-0.3.13\ext\mysql2/re
>   sult.c:403: undefined reference to `mysql_num_fields@4' result.o: In
>   function`nogvl_fetch_row':
>   c:\RailsInstaller\Ruby1.9.3\lib\ruby\gems\1.9.1\gems\mysql2-0.3.13\ext\mysql2/re
>   sult.c:105: undefined reference to `mysql_fetch_row@4' result.o: In
>   function`rb_mysql_result_free_result':
>   c:\RailsInstaller\Ruby1.9.3\lib\ruby\gems\1.9.1\gems\mysql2-0.3.13\ext\mysql2/re
>   sult.c:75: undefined reference to `mysql_free_result@4' result.o: In
>   function`rb_mysql_result_fetch_row':
>   c:\RailsInstaller\Ruby1.9.3\lib\ruby\gems\1.9.1\gems\mysql2-0.3.13\ext\mysql2/re
>   sult.c:213: undefined reference to `mysql_fetch_lengths@4'
>   c:\RailsInstaller\Ruby1.9.3\lib\ruby\gems\1.9.1\gems\mysql2-0.3.13\ext\mysql2/re
>   sult.c:215: undefined reference to`mysql_num_fields@4' result.o: In
>   function `rb_mysql_result_each':
>   c:\RailsInstaller\Ruby1.9.3\lib\ruby\gems\1.9.1\gems\mysql2-0.3.13\ext\mysql2/re
>   sult.c:503: undefined reference to`mysql_fetch_fields@4' result.o: In
>   function `rb_mysql_result_free_result':
>   c:\RailsInstaller\Ruby1.9.3\lib\ruby\gems\1.9.1\gems\mysql2-0.3.13\ext\mysql2/re
>   sult.c:75: undefined reference to`mysql_free_result@4' result.o: In
>   function `rb_mysql_result_each':
>   c:\RailsInstaller\Ruby1.9.3\lib\ruby\gems\1.9.1\gems\mysql2-0.3.13\ext\mysql2/re
>   sult.c:531: undefined reference to`mysql_fetch_fields@4' result.o: In
>   function `rb_mysql_result_free_result':
>   c:\RailsInstaller\Ruby1.9.3\lib\ruby\gems\1.9.1\gems\mysql2-0.3.13\ext\mysql2/re
>   sult.c:75: undefined reference to`mysql_free_result@4' result.o: In
>   function `rb_mysql_result_each':
>   c:\RailsInstaller\Ruby1.9.3\lib\ruby\gems\1.9.1\gems\mysql2-0.3.13\ext\mysql2/re
>   sult.c:490: undefined reference to`mysql_num_rows@4' result.o: In
>   function `rb_mysql_result_free_result':
>   c:\RailsInstaller\Ruby1.9.3\lib\ruby\gems\1.9.1\gems\mysql2-0.3.13\ext\mysql2/re
>   sult.c:75: undefined reference to`mysql_free_result@4' collect2: ld
>   returned 1 exit status make: *** [mysql2.so] Error 1
>
> ```
>     Gem files will remain installed in c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9 .1/gems/mysql2-0.3.13
> ```
>
> for inspection. Results logged to
>   c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/mysql2-0.
>           3.13/ext/mysql2/gem_make.out
>
> ```
> Can anyone please help?  I am having much trouble comprehending what's wrong with the installation.
> ```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I had this same error on Win64 environment.

I tested a lot of solutions but the only that worked for me was:

- gem install mysql2 -v '0.3.11'

Answer (score 9):

I've been so annoyed by the same problem, and finally succeeded in installing `mysql2`. Kudos to [odiszapc@github](https://github.com/odiszapc). It appears any other solution I've found via Google than below doesn't work to me.

Copied and pasted from [here](https://github.com/brianmario/mysql2/issues/359). So no credit to me.

```
gem uninstall mysql2

Download last MySQL connector from http://cdn.mysql.com/Downloads/Connector-C/mysql-    connector-c-noinstall-6.0.2-win32.zip

Extract it to C:\connector-6.0.2

gem install mysql2 --platform=ruby -- '--with-mysql-lib="C:\connector-6.0.2\lib" --with-mysql-include="C:\connector-6.0.2\include" --with-mysql-dir="C:\connector-6.0.2"'
```

Additional info on mine.

- ruby 1.9.3p392 (2013-02-22) [i386-mingw32]
- Rails 3.2.13
- MySQL Server 5.6
- mysql2-0.3.13

P.S
Even if you successfully installed `mysql2`, you may still need some work (e.g. mysql2.so (LoadError)), and it has something do with `libmysql` in my case, and seems like yet another major glitch about mysql2.

Comment: I had to remove lib an include options for some reason because it was complaining that it couldn't find them...weird...

So for me it was: gem install mysql2 --platform=ruby -- '--with-mysql-dir="C:\\connector-6.0.2"'

Answer (score 2):

I am installing on Windows 7 64 bit.  What worked for me was:

Download the C 32 bit connector archive from: http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/c/

I extracted it to C:\Temp.  If you use a different directory, adjust the next command.

```
gem install mysql2 --platform=ruby -- '--with-mysql-dir="C:\Temp\mysql-connector-c-6.1.3-win32"'
```

Answer (score 0):

pain... lot of pain. Finally working doing:

(Platform: Windows64bits, Ruby32bits, DevKit32bits...)

1. Download mysql connector for C from http://dev.mysql.com/get/Downloads/Connector-C/mysql-connector-c-noinstall-6.0.2-win32.zip/from/pick
2. Unzip connector in a directory without spaces in names!
3. Copy lib/libmysql.dll file into ruby/bin one
4. gem install mysql2 -- --with-mysql-dir=D:\RoR\mysql-connector-c (so give the dir of connector and not the dir of server)

And I got mysql2 v0.3.17 up and running...

Answer (score -1):

1. Download Mysql connector from 
   http://dev.mysql.com/get/Downloads/Connector-C/mysql-connector-c-noinstall-6.0.2-win32.zip/from/pick.
2. Extract it. copy *lib\libmysql.dll* file and paste it in Ruby's bin directory ex: *C:\RailsInstaller\Ruby1.9.3\bin*
3. Now again install Mysql2 gem
    gem install mysql2 -- '--with-mysql-lib="c:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.0\lib\opt" --with-mysql-include="c:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.0\include"'

   note: change mysql installation path as per yours
4. Try to bundle now