# Rails server not loading a page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

I'm working on a Rails 3.2.13 app, and I ran `rails server`.

The server works fine, but only until I tried render this page:

```
localhost:3000/items/1/edit
```

From this point on, any page I try to go to wouldn't get loaded.  The strange thing is, there are no error messages shown on the log.  The log just looks like it stopped responding.

As more background information, this morning I tried switching from sqlite to MySQL, and before that, the rails server worked just fine.  I then gave up on the installation of the mysql gem (because of the [error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17866003/rails-installing-mysql-error-installing-mysql2-error-failed-to-build-gem-nat)), and went back to my old `database.yml` and gemfile, so I don't suppose the installation attempt would've affected it.

Does anyone have any idea what is happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally figured it out.  Turns out I was rendering a partial that broke the page. 
Now the problem is fixed.

More specifically, I had a embedded ruby while loop in the partial, and the stopping condition was never met.  So essentially I was rendering an infinite loop, which explains the unresponsive behavior.

Answer (score 4):

A few ideas:

Try running `rake routes` (in the command line of your current working directory, not in the server)just to make sure you're `item/:id/edit` exists.

if it doesn't work you'd want to run something to the tune of

```
resources :items
```

If you only want to show the new and edit routes, try this:

```
resources :items, only: [:edit,:new]
```

If that's not the case, check to see if your `item/:id/edit` is set to be a get and not a post. If it's a post, and you're not posting, it will not work.

Finally, be sure to run `bundle update`.

The only other issue I could consider is you might have created a blank edit.html.erb view with nothing showing up.

Comment: the routing looks fine, ran bundle update, and the edit.html.erb isn't blank, but it's still not working...

Comment: There's absolutely nothing on your server log?

Comment: absolutely nothing. It's like dead as soon as I try rendering /items/1/edit page. No more new lines after that point