# ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension - Error installing mysql2

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, bundler

error while running bundle install

```
Installing mysql2 (0.3.11) with native extensions 
Gem::Installer::ExtensionBuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.
...
Make sure that `gem install mysql2 -v '0.3.11'` succeeds before bundling.
```

when i run Make sure that `gem install mysql2 -v '0.3.11'`.I still get the same error.

Answer (score 106, accepted):

which OS are you using?

anyway if you are **using ubuntu**, from this https://github.com/brianmario/mysql2/issues/8
run:

```
sudo apt-get install mysql-client libmysqlclient-dev
```

---

Otherwise for **Mac users**,(use brew to install) check this [Link](https://brew.sh), or run:

```
brew install mysql
```

then

```
sudo gem install mysql2
```

---

and for **windows users** check the link below for a solution.
[Error installing mysql2: Failed to build gem native extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3608287/error-installing-mysql2-failed-to-build-gem-native-extension/9317994#9317994)

I would recommend to use the normal command prompt.

Comment: Great. This fixed the issue I had installing Gitlab.

Answer (score 1):

Try to install these packages:

```
sudo apt-get install libmysqlclient-dev

sudo apt-get install bundler
```

After installing the bundler, run:

```
gem install mysql2
```

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes you need to update your Ruby library, run this code:

```
sudo gem update --system
```

Answer (score 0):

If the stack trace includes this error:

```
mkmf.rb can't find header files for ruby at /usr/lib/ruby/include/ruby.h
```

Look at what version of ruby you're using with:

```
ruby -v
```

Then install the correct version of ruby dev that goes with your version of ruby:

```
sudo apt-get install ruby2.0-dev
sudo apt-get install ruby2.2-dev
sudo apt-get install ruby2.3-dev
```

Then:

```
gem install mysql2
```

Answer (score 0):

This thread helped in installing mysql2

[Github thread on installing mysql2 on OSX Mojave](https://gist.github.com/fernandoaleman/ee3ac6957c2ba4f7d7d33a251d58b191)

as mentioned in the thread I tried

```
$ bundle config build.mysql2 --with-opt-dir=/usr/local/opt/openssl
```