# Failed to install "Mysql2" version 0.5.2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I tried all methods of [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3608287/error-installing-mysql2-failed-to-build-gem-native-extension).
But still, the same error occurs.

```
An error occurred while installing mysql2 (0.5.2), and Bundler cannot
continue.
Make sure that gem install mysql2 -v '0.5.2' --source 'https://rubygems.org/'
succeeds before bundling.
```

My spec is:

- MacOS Mojave 10.14.1
- Ruby 2.5.3p105
- Mysql 8.0.12 with Homebrew

Gemfile:

```
gem "rails"
gem "mysql2", "0.5.2"
```

Could you kindly tell me a solution?

Comment: When you run `gem install mysql2 -v '0.5.2' --source 'https://rubygems.org/'`, what is the output?

Comment: I tried to install older versions of Mysql2 0.5.1, 0.5.0, too. But it is failed...

Comment: Hi, Sara
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Errno::EACCES)
    Permission denied @ rb_sysopen - /Users/daisuke/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/mysql2-0.5.2/CHANGELOG.md

Comment: I did sudo, too.

sudo gem install mysql2 -v '0.5.2' --source 'https://rubygems.org/'
Password:
Building native extensions. This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing mysql2:
 ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

Comment: Hi,  hernanvicente.
macOS Mojave 10.14.1

Comment: Sorry, I did missread your comment above. Could you please share share the result of your trace? Try to run your instruction appending a `--trace`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension - Error installing mysql2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19765290/error-failed-to-build-gem-native-extension-error-installing-mysql2)

Comment: I think that you are probably missing to install some dev package dependency. Try: `brew install mysql-connector-c` and then later `brew install libmysqlclient-dev`

Comment: brew install libmysqlclient-dev
Error: No available formula with the name "libmysqlclient-dev" 
==> Searching for a previously deleted formula (in the last month)...
Warning: homebrew/core is shallow clone. To get complete history run:
  git -C "$(brew --repo homebrew/core)" fetch --unshallow

Error: No previously deleted formula found.
==> Searching for similarly named formulae...
Error: No similarly named formulae found.
==> Searching taps...
==> Searching taps on GitHub...
Error: No formulae found in taps.

Comment: @Daisuke can you try to install your mysql gem providing the actual mysql directory. Check https://coderwall.com/p/whbzrw/install-mysql2-gem-in-mac-os-x-with-mysql-installed-via-brew

Comment: @hernanvicente I did it. however...
sudo gem install mysql2 -- --with-mysql-dir=/usr/local/bin/mysql
Building native extensions with: '--with-mysql-dir=/usr/local/bin/mysql'
This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing mysql2:
ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

Answer (score 0):

This is a very good post. I was facing the same issue using mac. What I ended up doing was the following.

1. I changed the permission for the Gemfile. I used `chmod 755 Gemfile`.
2. I used `sudo bundle install`. This allowed me to install all the gems in the Gemfile.
3. I did a `rake db:create` and `rails server`.

Got things working. Hope it fixes your issue too.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, when setting up a new machine.

Just running

`brew install mysql`

fixed the failing mysql gem installation for me.

Answer (score 0):

Don't know if this will help, but I had imilar problems on Mac with MySQL twice. First time I just did a complete reinstall, I made sure there were no MySQL files left in the system. I think I followed [this](https://gist.github.com/vitorbritto/0555879fe4414d18569d) guide. The second time I read that it's an issue with symoblic links which I managed to fix with `brew prune` (I see that it might have been [renamed](https://discourse.brew.sh/t/error-calling-brew-prune-is-disabled/4142) to `brew cleanup` now - worth to check both).