# gem mysql2 not installed on ruby on rails

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, c, ruby, mysql2

I have installed following versions:

- ruby 1.9.3p484 (2013-11-22) [i386-mingw32]
- rails 4.0.2
- DevKit-tdm-32-4.5.2-20111229-1559-sfx
- rubygems-2.1.11
- MySQL Server 5.6
- mysql-connector-c-noinstall-6.0.2-win32-vs2005

I have run following three commands:

```
$ gem i mysql2

$ gem install mysql2 -- '--with-mysql-lib="C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6\lib" --with-mysql-include="C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6\include" --with-mysql-dir="C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6"'

$ gem install mysql2 --platform=ruby -- '--with-mysql-lib="C:\mysql-connector-c-noinstall-6.0.2-win32-vs2005\lib" --with-mysql-include="C:\mysql-connector-c-noinstall-6.0.2-win32-vs2005\include" --with-mysql-dir="C:\mysql-connector-c-noinstall-6.0.2-win32-vs2005"'
```

above three cmds have following ERROR:

```
* extconf.rb failed * Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary libraries and/or headers. Check the mkmf.log file for more details. You may need configuration options.
```

Answer (score 0):

sudo apt-get install libmysql-ruby libmysqlclient-dev

look at this question https://stackoverflow.com/a/3608756/1970061