# An error occurred while installing mysql2 (0.3.16), and Bundler cannot continue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a problem when I run bundle install  . I am a nowbie .  I need use mysql as database for my application
I haven't idea how resolve this problem
Can someone give me some advice?

I am using ruby 1.9.3 and

Rails 3.2.19

My problem starts here When I try create the application with rails generate

```
fernando@fernando:~/ruby$ rails new app2 -d mysql 
      create  
      create  README.rdoc
      create  Rakefile
      create  config.ru
      create  .gitignore
      create  Gemfile
      create  app
      create  app/assets/images/rails.png
      create  app/assets/javascripts/application.js
      create  app/assets/stylesheets/application.css
      create  app/controllers/application_controller.rb
      create  app/helpers/application_helper.rb
      create  app/mailers
      create  app/models
      create  app/views/layouts/application.html.erb
      create  app/mailers/.gitkeep
      create  app/models/.gitkeep
      create  config
      create  config/routes.rb
      create  config/application.rb
      create  config/environment.rb
      create  config/environments
      create  config/environments/development.rb
      create  config/environments/production.rb
      create  config/environments/test.rb
      create  config/initializers
      create  config/initializers/backtrace_silencers.rb
      create  config/initializers/inflections.rb
      create  config/initializers/mime_types.rb
      create  config/initializers/secret_token.rb
      create  config/initializers/session_store.rb
      create  config/initializers/wrap_parameters.rb
      create  config/locales
      create  config/locales/en.yml
      create  config/boot.rb
      create  config/database.yml
      create  db
      create  db/seeds.rb
      create  doc
      create  doc/README_FOR_APP
      create  lib
      create  lib/tasks
      create  lib/tasks/.gitkeep
      create  lib/assets
      create  lib/assets/.gitkeep
      create  log
      create  log/.gitkeep
      create  public
      create  public/404.html
      create  public/422.html
      create  public/500.html
      create  public/favicon.ico
      create  public/index.html
      create  public/robots.txt
      create  script
      create  script/rails
      create  test/fixtures
      create  test/fixtures/.gitkeep
      create  test/functional
      create  test/functional/.gitkeep
      create  test/integration
      create  test/integration/.gitkeep
      create  test/unit
      create  test/unit/.gitkeep
      create  test/performance/browsing_test.rb
      create  test/test_helper.rb
      create  tmp/cache
      create  tmp/cache/assets
      create  vendor/assets/javascripts
      create  vendor/assets/javascripts/.gitkeep
      create  vendor/assets/stylesheets
      create  vendor/assets/stylesheets/.gitkeep
      create  vendor/plugins
      create  vendor/plugins/.gitkeep
         run  bundle install
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/.........Retrying dependency api due to error (2/3): Bundler::HTTPError Network error while fetching https://bundler.rubygems.org/api/v1/dependencies?gems=rspec-support,multi_test,gherkin,cucumber-core,term-ansicolor,highline,allison
..
Resolving dependencies...
Using rake 10.3.2
Using i18n 0.6.11
Using multi_json 1.10.1
Using activesupport 3.2.19
Using builder 3.0.4
Using activemodel 3.2.19
Using erubis 2.7.0
Using journey 1.0.4
Using rack 1.4.5
Using rack-cache 1.2
Using rack-test 0.6.2
Using hike 1.2.3
Using tilt 1.4.1
Using sprockets 2.2.2
Using actionpack 3.2.19
Using mime-types 1.25.1
Using polyglot 0.3.5
Using treetop 1.4.15
Using mail 2.5.4
Using actionmailer 3.2.19
Using arel 3.0.3
Using tzinfo 0.3.41
Using activerecord 3.2.19
Using activeresource 3.2.19
Using bundler 1.6.2
Using coffee-script-source 1.8.0
Using execjs 2.2.1
Using coffee-script 2.3.0
Using rack-ssl 1.3.4
Using json 1.8.1
Using rdoc 3.12.2
Using thor 0.19.1
Using railties 3.2.19
Using coffee-rails 3.2.2
Using jquery-rails 3.1.2

Gem::Ext::BuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    /home/fernando/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p547/bin/ruby extconf.rb 
checking for ruby/thread.h... no
checking for rb_thread_blocking_region()... yes
checking for rb_wait_for_single_fd()... yes
checking for rb_hash_dup()... yes
checking for rb_intern3()... yes
checking for mysql_query() in -lmysqlclient... no
checking for main() in -lm... yes
checking for mysql_query() in -lmysqlclient... no
checking for main() in -lz... yes
checking for mysql_query() in -lmysqlclient... no
checking for main() in -lsocket... no
checking for mysql_query() in -lmysqlclient... no
checking for main() in -lnsl... yes
checking for mysql_query() in -lmysqlclient... no
checking for main() in -lmygcc... no
checking for mysql_query() in -lmysqlclient... no
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of
necessary libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more
details.  You may need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
    --with-opt-dir
    --without-opt-dir
    --with-opt-include
    --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
    --with-opt-lib
    --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
    --with-make-prog
    --without-make-prog
    --srcdir=.
    --curdir
    --ruby=/home/fernando/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p547/bin/ruby
    --with-mysql-dir
    --without-mysql-dir
    --with-mysql-include
    --without-mysql-include=${mysql-dir}/include
    --with-mysql-lib
    --without-mysql-lib=${mysql-dir}/lib
    --with-mysql-config
    --without-mysql-config
    --with-mysql-dir
    --without-mysql-dir
    --with-mysql-include
    --without-mysql-include=${mysql-dir}/include
    --with-mysql-lib
    --without-mysql-lib=${mysql-dir}/lib
    --with-mysqlclientlib
    --without-mysqlclientlib
    --with-mlib
    --without-mlib
    --with-mysqlclientlib
    --without-mysqlclientlib
    --with-zlib
    --without-zlib
    --with-mysqlclientlib
    --without-mysqlclientlib
    --with-socketlib
    --without-socketlib
    --with-mysqlclientlib
    --without-mysqlclientlib
    --with-nsllib
    --without-nsllib
    --with-mysqlclientlib
    --without-mysqlclientlib
    --with-mygcclib
    --without-mygcclib
    --with-mysqlclientlib
    --without-mysqlclientlib

extconf failed, exit code 1

Gem files will remain installed in /home/fernando/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p547@ruby-guides/gems/mysql2-0.3.16 for inspection.
Results logged to /home/fernando/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p547@ruby-guides/extensions/x86-linux/1.9.1/mysql2-0.3.16/gem_make.out
An error occurred while installing mysql2 (0.3.16), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install mysql2 -v '0.3.16'` succeeds before bundling
```

.

```
fernando@fernando:~/ruby/app$ bundle
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/...........
Resolving dependencies...
Using rake 10.3.2
Using i18n 0.6.11
Using multi_json 1.10.1
Using activesupport 3.2.19
Using builder 3.0.4
Using activemodel 3.2.19
Using erubis 2.7.0
Using journey 1.0.4
Using rack 1.4.5
Using rack-cache 1.2
Using rack-test 0.6.2
Using hike 1.2.3
Using tilt 1.4.1
Using sprockets 2.2.2
Using actionpack 3.2.19
Using mime-types 1.25.1
Using polyglot 0.3.5
Using treetop 1.4.15
Using mail 2.5.4
Using actionmailer 3.2.19
Using arel 3.0.3
Using tzinfo 0.3.41
Using activerecord 3.2.19
Using activeresource 3.2.19
Using bundler 1.6.2
Using coffee-script-source 1.8.0
Using execjs 2.2.1
Using coffee-script 2.3.0
Using rack-ssl 1.3.4
Using json 1.8.1
Using rdoc 3.12.2
Using thor 0.19.1
Using railties 3.2.19
Using coffee-rails 3.2.2
Using jquery-rails 3.1.2

Gem::Ext::BuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    /home/fernando/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p547/bin/ruby extconf.rb 
checking for ruby/thread.h... no
checking for rb_thread_blocking_region()... yes
checking for rb_wait_for_single_fd()... yes
checking for rb_hash_dup()... yes
checking for rb_intern3()... yes
checking for mysql_query() in -lmysqlclient... no
checking for main() in -lm... yes
checking for mysql_query() in -lmysqlclient... no
checking for main() in -lz... yes
checking for mysql_query() in -lmysqlclient... no
checking for main() in -lsocket... no
checking for mysql_query() in -lmysqlclient... no
checking for main() in -lnsl... yes
checking for mysql_query() in -lmysqlclient... no
checking for main() in -lmygcc... no
checking for mysql_query() in -lmysqlclient... no
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of
necessary libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more
details.  You may need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
    --with-opt-dir
    --without-opt-dir
    --with-opt-include
    --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
    --with-opt-lib
    --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
    --with-make-prog
    --without-make-prog
    --srcdir=.
    --curdir
    --ruby=/home/fernando/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p547/bin/ruby
    --with-mysql-dir
    --without-mysql-dir
    --with-mysql-include
    --without-mysql-include=${mysql-dir}/include
    --with-mysql-lib
    --without-mysql-lib=${mysql-dir}/lib
    --with-mysql-config
    --without-mysql-config
    --with-mysql-dir
    --without-mysql-dir
    --with-mysql-include
    --without-mysql-include=${mysql-dir}/include
    --with-mysql-lib
    --without-mysql-lib=${mysql-dir}/lib
    --with-mysqlclientlib
    --without-mysqlclientlib
    --with-mlib
    --without-mlib
    --with-mysqlclientlib
    --without-mysqlclientlib
    --with-zlib
    --without-zlib
    --with-mysqlclientlib
    --without-mysqlclientlib
    --with-socketlib
    --without-socketlib
    --with-mysqlclientlib
    --without-mysqlclientlib
    --with-nsllib
    --without-nsllib
    --with-mysqlclientlib
    --without-mysqlclientlib
    --with-mygcclib
    --without-mygcclib
    --with-mysqlclientlib
    --without-mysqlclientlib

extconf failed, exit code 1

Gem files will remain installed in /home/fernando/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p547@ruby-guides/gems/mysql2-0.3.16 for inspection.
Results logged to /home/fernando/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p547@ruby-guides/extensions/x86-linux/1.9.1/mysql2-0.3.16/gem_make.out
An error occurred while installing mysql2 (0.3.16), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install mysql2 -v '0.3.16'` succeeds before bundling.
```

Answer (score 8):

On Ubuntu/Debian and other distributions using aptitude:

```
sudo apt-get install libmysql-ruby libmysqlclient-dev
```

If the above command doesn't work because libmysql-ruby cannot be found, the following should be sufficient:

[Error installing mysql2: Failed to build gem native extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3608287/error-installing-mysql2-failed-to-build-gem-native-extension)

Comment: On Debian 8 you can now just do `sudo apt-get install libmysqlclient-dev`.