# Weird mysql error `checking for main() in -llibmysql... no`

Tags: mysql, ruby, rubygems

I've successfully installed the gem mysql2 with ruby under windows in the past, but now it's showing a weird error

```
checking for main() in -llibmysql... no
```

There is no typo, my console really shows `-llibmysql` and not `-libmysql` (and I think it should even be just `libmysql` without any dash)

I have followed all the instructions from [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3608287/error-installing-mysql2-failed-to-build-gem-native-extension), and my command looks like

```
gem install mysql2 -- '--with-mysql-lib="c:\Dev\MySQL_Connector\lib" --with-mysql-include="c:\Dev\MySQL_Connector\include"'
...

ERROR:  Error installing mysql2:
        ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    C:/Bibliotheques/Dev/Ruby200-x64/bin/ruby.exe extconf.rb --with-mysql-lib=c:\Dev\MySQL_Connector\lib --with-mysql-in
clude=c:\Dev\MySQL_Connector\include
checking for ruby/thread.h... yes
checking for rb_thread_call_without_gvl() in ruby/thread.h... yes
checking for rb_thread_blocking_region()... yes
checking for rb_wait_for_single_fd()... yes
checking for rb_hash_dup()... yes
checking for rb_intern3()... yes
-----
Using --with-mysql-dir=c:\Dev\MySQL_Connector
-----
checking for main() in -llibmysql... no
```

Comment: Which version of ruby?

Comment: probably you can look around this thread for solutions https://github.com/brianmario/mysql2/issues/364

Comment: Sorry it's been some time and no news from me. I actually switched to the x86 version of ruby, and then did the code modification for the "pow" stuff `https://github.com/mongoid/mongoid/issues/3489`