# Error bundle install - "mysql2"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, macos

When I run " bundle install " I get the following error:

```
An error occurred while installing mysql2 (0.3.17), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install mysql2 -v '0.3.17'` succeeds before bundling.
```

And when I try to run the command `gem install mysql2 -v '0.3.17'` I get the error:

```
ERROR:  Error installing mysql2:
ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.
```

[Complete log](http://justpaste.it/i3cj)

I've tried reinstalling and installing the rails.

I'm on a MacOs.

Anyone? Thanks!

Comment: provide build log please

Comment: You will get verified answer here:
[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3608287/error-installing-mysql2-failed-to-build-gem-native-extension][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3608287/error-installing-mysql2-failed-to-build-gem-native-extension

Comment: I saw these topics , but it still fails.

Comment: @МалъСкрылевъ http://justpaste.it/i3cj

Comment: there are all kinds of issues that people have had installing mysql2. google around, and check out https://github.com/brianmario/mysql2/issues

Comment: What was the error that occurred? This is missing from your question.

Comment: I just need to install mysql gem... and appears me this error

Answer (score 2):

If you are using homebrew:

```
brew install mysql
```

then

```
gem install mysql2 -v '0.3.17'
```

Comment: It did not work , I got an error when installing the gem again.