# Error installing sqlite3, Failed to build gem native extension

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sqlite, rubygems, installation

I've referred to the following solution on stackoverflow, yet I'm still experiencing the same issue:

> ([Error installing mysql2: Failed to build gem native extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3608287/error-installing-mysql2-failed-to-build-gem-native-extension)),

The below command referenced in the link above did not remediate the issue:

> brew install mysql

Evidently, the issue persists, returning the following output:

```
Gem::Installer::ExtensionBuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/bin/ruby extconf.rb
checking for sqlite3.h... yes
checking for sqlite3_libversion_number() in -lsqlite3... no
sqlite3 is missing. Try 'port install sqlite3 +universal',
'yum install sqlite-devel' or 'apt-get install libsqlite3-dev'
and check your shared library search path (the
location where your sqlite3 shared library is located).
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
    --with-opt-dir
    --without-opt-dir
    --with-opt-include
    --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
    --with-opt-lib
    --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
    --with-make-prog
    --without-make-prog
    --srcdir=.
    --curdir
    --ruby=/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/bin/ruby
    --with-sqlite3-dir
    --without-sqlite3-dir
    --with-sqlite3-include
    --without-sqlite3-include=${sqlite3-dir}/include
    --with-sqlite3-lib
    --without-sqlite3-lib=${sqlite3-dir}/
    --with-sqlite3lib
    --without-sqlite3lib


Gem files will remain installed in /var/folders/fb/tvgwnxc10lq6kd5xxwcg_0nw0000gn/T/bundler20150210-28601-nw7oyi/sqlite3-1.3.10/gems/sqlite3-1.3.10 for inspection.
Results logged to /var/folders/fb/tvgwnxc10lq6kd5xxwcg_0nw0000gn/T/bundler20150210-28601-nw7oyi/sqlite3-1.3.10/gems/sqlite3-1.3.10/ext/sqlite3/gem_make.out
An error occurred while installing sqlite3 (1.3.10), and Bundler cannot
continue.
Make sure that `gem install sqlite3 -v '1.3.10'` succeeds before bundling.
➜  code
```

I would sincerely appreciate assistance.  Thank you!

Comment: Are you on RHEL/Centos/Fedora? Have you tried `yum install sqlite-devel`?

Comment: Neither-I'm operating Mac OS X Yosemite.  Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The following commands remediated my issue:

1. `brew unlink sqlite`
2. `brew install sqlite3 --universal`
3. `sudo gem install sqlite3 -- --with-sqlite3-dir=/usr/local/Cellar/sqlite/3.8.8.1`

My long-time friend working in InfoSec assisted me.  According to him, my SQLite3 updates were directing to the wrong bin.  I hope this helps anyone experiencing the same frustrating issue.  Thank you!

Comment: This worked great for me.  I did `sudo gem install sqlite3 -- --with-sqlite3-dir=/usr/local/Cellar/sqlite/3.8.10.2`.  I'm on Yosemite.

Comment: You always have to check, what version you have installed with `ls -l /usr/local/Cellar/sqlite/` and use the latest version folder.