# How to install mysql2 on Ubuntu 16.04 [ ERROR: Error installing mysql2: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.]

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ubuntu

I don't know install mysql2 on ubuntu :(

```
sudo gem install mysql2
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing mysql2:
ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

current directory: /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/mysql2-0.4.4/ext/mysql2
/usr/bin/ruby2.3 -r ./siteconf20160515-9715-1s2u1sj.rb extconf.rb
mkmf.rb can't find header files for ruby at /usr/lib/ruby/include/ruby.h

extconf failed, exit code 1

Gem files will remain installed in /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/mysql2-0.4.4 for inspection.
Results logged to /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/extensions/x86_64-linux/2.3.0/mysql2-0.4.4/gem_make.out
```

**sudo apt-get install libmysqlclient-dev**

```
Lendo listas de pacotes... Pronto
Construindo árvore de dependências       
Lendo informação de estado... Pronto
libmysqlclient-dev is already the newest version (5.7.12-0ubuntu1).
0 pacotes atualizados, 0 pacotes novos instalados, 0 a serem removidos e 61 não atualizados.
```

**but is not working**

Comment: rake test
  `Could not find gem 'mysql2 (< 0.5, >= 0.3.13)' in any of the gem sources listed in your Gemfile or available on this machine.`
Run `bundle install` to install missing gems.

Comment: Do you have ruby dev environment installed? `sudo apt-get install ruby-dev`

Comment: Check if you have all the other requirements to build the native extensions of the mysql2 gem.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3608287/error-installing-mysql2-failed-to-build-gem-native-extension

Answer (score 50):

First, install libmysqlclient-dev using:

```
sudo apt-get install libmysqlclient-dev
```

Then:

```
bundle
```

Answer (score 6):

```
sudo apt-get install libnetcdf-dev libssl-dev libcrypto++-dev libgmp-dev
```

has resolved same issue for me

Answer (score 1):

```
sudo apt-get install ruby-mysql2
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Comment: This way is installing  the "ruby-mysql2" OS package which might result in  installing wrong or too old versions (depends on the OS)