# Unable to mysql2 gem on windows 11 due to SSL issues - all other gems work

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ssl, rubygems, mysql2

I'm trying to install the mysql2 gem using RoR 8.16.0, and I keep on getting SSL errors.
I've made sure all my certs are installed correctly. I have no issues with any other gems, and I can't seem to find the problem. Pretty frustrating, as I can't get any work done without my DB.

I ran:

```
gem install mysql2
```

here is the result:

```
Temporarily enhancing PATH for MSYS/MINGW...
Installing required msys2 packages: mingw-w64-ucrt-x86_64-libmariadbclient
error: failed retrieving file 'mingw-w64-ucrt-x86_64-openssl-1.1.1.n-1-any.pkg.tar.zst' from mirror.msys2.org : SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate
error: failed retrieving file 'mingw-w64-ucrt-x86_64-libxml2-2.9.13-1-any.pkg.tar.zst' from mirror.msys2.org : SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate
error: failed retrieving file 'mingw-w64-ucrt-x86_64-curl-7.82.0-1-any.pkg.tar.zst' from mirror.msys2.org : SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate
warning: too many errors from mirror.msys2.org, skipping for the remainder of this transaction
error: failed retrieving file 'mingw-w64-ucrt-x86_64-libunistring-0.9.10-4-any.pkg.tar.zst' from mirror.msys2.org : SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate
error: failed retrieving file 'mingw-w64-ucrt-x86_64-brotli-1.0.9-4-any.pkg.tar.zst' from mirror.msys2.org : SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate
error: failed retrieving file 'mingw-w64-ucrt-x86_64-openssl-1.1.1.n-1-any.pkg.tar.zst' from repo.msys2.org : SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate
error: failed retrieving file 'mingw-w64-ucrt-x86_64-libxml2-2.9.13-1-any.pkg.tar.zst' from repo.msys2.org : SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate
error: failed retrieving file 'mingw-w64-ucrt-x86_64-curl-7.82.0-1-any.pkg.tar.zst' from repo.msys2.org : SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate
warning: too many errors from repo.msys2.org, skipping for the remainder of this transaction
error: failed retrieving file 'mingw-w64-ucrt-x86_64-libunistring-0.9.10-4-any.pkg.tar.zst' from download.nus.edu.sg : SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate
error: failed retrieving file 'mingw-w64-ucrt-x86_64-brotli-1.0.9-4-any.pkg.tar.zst' from download.nus.edu.sg : SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate
error: failed retrieving file 'mingw-w64-ucrt-x86_64-openssl-1.1.1.n-1-any.pkg.tar.zst' from ftp.acc.umu.se : SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate
error: failed retrieving file 'mingw-w64-ucrt-x86_64-libxml2-2.9.13-1-any.pkg.tar.zst' from ftp.acc.umu.se : SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate
error: failed retrieving file 'mingw-w64-ucrt-x86_64-curl-7.82.0-1-any.pkg.tar.zst' from ftp.acc.umu.se : SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate
warning: too many errors from ftp.acc.umu.se, skipping for the remainder of this transaction
error: failed retrieving file 'mingw-w64-ucrt-x86_64-libunistring-0.9.10-4-any.pkg.tar.zst' from ftp.acc.umu.se : SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate
error: failed retrieving file 'mingw-w64-ucrt-x86_64-brotli-1.0.9-4-any.pkg.tar.zst' from ftp.acc.umu.se : SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate
error: failed retrieving file 'mingw-w64-ucrt-x86_64-openssl-1.1.1.n-1-any.pkg.tar.zst' from ftp.nluug.nl : SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate
error: failed retrieving file 'mingw-w64-ucrt-x86_64-libxml2-2.9.13-1-any.pkg.tar.zst' from ftp.nluug.nl : SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate
error: failed retrieving file 'mingw-w64-ucrt-x86_64-curl-7.82.0-1-any.pkg.tar.zst' from ftp.nluug.nl : SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate
warning: too many errors from ftp.nluug.nl, skipping for the remainder of this transaction
error: failed retrieving file 'mingw-w64-ucrt-x86_64-libunistring-0.9.10-4-any.pkg.tar.zst' from ftp.nluug.nl : SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate
error: failed retrieving file 'mingw-w64-ucrt-x86_64-brotli-1.0.9-4-any.pkg.tar.zst' from ftp.nluug.nl : SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate
error: failed retrieving file 'mingw-w64-ucrt-x86_64-openssl-1.1.1.n-1-any.pkg.tar.zst' from ftp.osuosl.org : SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate
error: failed retrieving file 'mingw-w64-ucrt-x86_64-libxml2-2.9.13-1-any.pkg.tar.zst' from ftp.osuosl.org : SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate
error: failed retrieving file 'mingw-w64-ucrt-x86_64-curl-7.82.0-1-any.pkg.tar.zst' from ftp.osuosl.org : SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate
warning: too many errors from ftp.osuosl.org, skipping for the remainder of this transaction
error: failed retrieving file 'mingw-w64-ucrt-x86_64-libunistring-0.9.10-4-any.pkg.tar.zst' from ftp.osuosl.org : SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate
error: failed retrieving file 'mingw-w64-ucrt-x86_64-brotli-1.0.9-4-any.pkg.tar.zst' from ftp.osuosl.org : SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate
error: failed retrieving file 'mingw-w64-ucrt-x86_64-openssl-1.1.1.n-1-any.pkg.tar.zst' from mirror.internet.asn.au : SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate
error: failed retrieving file 'mingw-w64-ucrt-x86_64-libxml2-2.9.13-1-any.pkg.tar.zst' from mirror.internet.asn.au : SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate
error: failed retrieving file 'mingw-w64-ucrt-x86_64-curl-7.82.0-1-any.pkg.tar.zst' from mirror.internet.asn.au : SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate
warning: too many errors from mirror.internet.asn.au, skipping for the remainder of this transaction
error: failed retrieving file 'mingw-w64-ucrt-x86_64-libunistring-0.9.10-4-any.pkg.tar.zst' from mirror.internet.asn.au : SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate
error: failed retrieving file 'mingw-w64-ucrt-x86_64-brotli-1.0.9-4-any.pkg.tar.zst' from mirror.internet.asn.au : SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate
error: failed retrieving file 'mingw-w64-ucrt-x86_64-openssl-1.1.1.n-1-any.pkg.tar.zst' from mirror.selfnet.de : SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate
error: failed retrieving file 'mingw-w64-ucrt-x86_64-libxml2-2.9.13-1-any.pkg.tar.zst' from mirror.selfnet.de : SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate
error: failed retrieving file 'mingw-w64-ucrt-x86_64-curl-7.82.0-1-any.pkg.tar.zst' from mirror.selfnet.de : SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate
warning: too many errors from mirror.selfnet.de, skipping for the remainder of this transaction
error: failed retrieving file 'mingw-w64-ucrt-x86_64-libunistring-0.9.10-4-any.pkg.tar.zst' from mirror.selfnet.de : SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate
from mirrors.dotsrc.org : SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate
error: failed retrieving file 'mingw-w64-ucrt-x86_64-curl-7.82.0-1-any.pkg.tar.zst' from mirrors.dotsrc.org : SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate
warning: too many errors from mirrors.dotsrc.org, skipping for the remainder of this transaction
error: failed retrieving file 'mingw-w64-ucrt-x86_64-libunistring-0.9.10-4-any.pkg.tar.zst' from mirrors.dotsrc.org : SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate
error: failed retrieving file 'mingw-w64-ucrt-x86_64-brotli-1.0.9-4-any.pkg.tar.zst' from mirrors.dotsrc.org : SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate
error: failed retrieving file 'mingw-w64-ucrt-x86_64-openssl-1.1.1.n-1-any.pkg.tar.zst' from mirrors.bfsu.edu.cn : SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate
error: failed retrieving file 'mingw-w64-ucrt-x86_64-libxml2-2.9.13-1-any.pkg.tar.zst' from mirrors.bfsu.edu.cn : SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate
error: failed retrieving file 'mingw-w64-ucrt-x86_64-curl-7.82.0-1-any.pkg.tar.zst' from mirrors.bfsu.edu.cn : SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate
warning: too many errors from mirrors.bfsu.edu.cn, skipping for the remainder of this transaction
error: failed retrieving file 'mingw-w64-ucrt-x86_64-libunistring-0.9.10-4-any.pkg.tar.zst' from mirrors.bfsu.edu.cn : SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate
error: failed retrieving file 'mingw-w64-ucrt-x86_64-brotli-1.0.9-4-any.pkg.tar.zst' from mirrors.bfsu.edu.cn : SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate
error: failed retrieving file 'mingw-w64-ucrt-x86_64-openssl-1.1.1.n-1-any.pkg.tar.zst' from mirrors.tuna.tsinghua.edu.cn : SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate
error: failed retrieving file 'mingw-w64-ucrt-x86_64-libxml2-2.9.13-1-any.pkg.tar.zst' from mirrors.tuna.tsinghua.edu.cn : SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate
error: failed retrieving file 'mingw-w64-ucrt-x86_64-curl-7.82.0-1-any.pkg.tar.zst' from mirrors.tuna.tsinghua.edu.cn : SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate
warning: too many errors from mirrors.tuna.tsinghua.edu.cn, skipping for the remainder of this transaction
error: failed retrieving file 'mingw-w64-ucrt-x86_64-libunistring-0.9.10-4-any.pkg.tar.zst' from mirrors.tuna.tsinghua.edu.cn : SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate
error: failed retrieving file 'mingw-w64-ucrt-x86_64-brotli-1.0.9-4-any.pkg.tar.zst' from mirrors.tuna.tsinghua.edu.cn : SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate
error: failed retrieving file 'mingw-w64-ucrt-x86_64-openssl-1.1.1.n-1-any.pkg.tar.zst' from mirrors.ustc.edu.cn : SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate
error: failed retrieving file 'mingw-w64-ucrt-x86_64-libxml2-2.9.13-1-any.pkg.tar.zst' from mirrors.ustc.edu.cn : SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate
error: failed retrieving file 'mingw-w64-ucrt-x86_64-curl-7.82.0-1-any.pkg.tar.zst' from mirrors.ustc.edu.cn : SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate
warning: too many errors from mirrors.ustc.edu.cn, skipping for the remainder of this transaction
error: failed retrieving file 'mingw-w64-ucrt-x86_64-libunistring-0.9.10-4-any.pkg.tar.zst' from mirrors.ustc.edu.cn : SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate
error: failed retrieving file 'mingw-w64-ucrt-x86_64-brotli-1.0.9-4-any.pkg.tar.zst' from mirrors.ustc.edu.cn : SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate
error: failed retrieving file 'mingw-w64-ucrt-x86_64-openssl-1.1.1.n-1-any.pkg.tar.zst' from mirror.nju.edu.cn : SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate
error: failed retrieving file 'mingw-w64-ucrt-x86_64-libxml2-2.9.13-1-any.pkg.tar.zst' from mirror.nju.edu.cn : SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate
error: failed retrieving file 'mingw-w64-ucrt-x86_64-curl-7.82.0-1-any.pkg.tar.zst' from mirror.nju.edu.cn : SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate
warning: too many errors from mirror.nju.edu.cn, skipping for the remainder of this transaction
error: failed retrieving file 'mingw-w64-ucrt-x86_64-libunistring-0.9.10-4-any.pkg.tar.zst' from mirror.nju.edu.cn : SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate
error: failed retrieving file 'mingw-w64-ucrt-x86_64-brotli-1.0.9-4-any.pkg.tar.zst' from mirror.nju.edu.cn : SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate
error: failed retrieving file 'mingw-w64-ucrt-x86_64-openssl-1.1.1.n-1-any.pkg.tar.zst' from repo.extreme-ix.org : SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate
error: failed retrieving file 'mingw-w64-ucrt-x86_64-libxml2-2.9.13-1-any.pkg.tar.zst' from repo.extreme-ix.org : SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate
error: failed retrieving file 'mingw-w64-ucrt-x86_64-curl-7.82.0-1-any.pkg.tar.zst' from repo.extreme-ix.org : SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate
warning: too many errors from repo.extreme-ix.org, skipping for the remainder of this transaction
error: failed retrieving file 'mingw-w64-ucrt-x86_64-libunistring-0.9.10-4-any.pkg.tar.zst' from repo.extreme-ix.org : SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate
error: failed retrieving file 'mingw-w64-ucrt-x86_64-brotli-1.0.9-4-any.pkg.tar.zst' from repo.extreme-ix.org : SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate
error: failed retrieving file 'mingw-w64-ucrt-x86_64-openssl-1.1.1.n-1-any.pkg.tar.zst' from mirrors.hit.edu.cn : SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate
error: failed retrieving file 'mingw-w64-ucrt-x86_64-libxml2-2.9.13-1-any.pkg.tar.zst' from mirrors.hit.edu.cn : SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate
error: failed retrieving file 'mingw-w64-ucrt-x86_64-curl-7.82.0-1-any.pkg.tar.zst' from mirrors.hit.edu.cn : SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate
warning: too many errors from mirrors.hit.edu.cn, skipping for the remainder of this transaction
error: failed retrieving file 'mingw-w64-ucrt-x86_64-libunistring-0.9.10-4-any.pkg.tar.zst' from mirrors.hit.edu.cn : SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate
error: failed retrieving file 'mingw-w64-ucrt-x86_64-brotli-1.0.9-4-any.pkg.tar.zst' from mirrors.hit.edu.cn : SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate
error: failed retrieving file 'mingw-w64-ucrt-x86_64-openssl-1.1.1.n-1-any.pkg.tar.zst' from mirror.clarkson.edu : SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate
error: failed retrieving file 'mingw-w64-ucrt-x86_64-libxml2-2.9.13-1-any.pkg.tar.zst' from mirror.clarkson.edu : SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate
error: failed retrieving file 'mingw-w64-ucrt-x86_64-curl-7.82.0-1-any.pkg.tar.zst' from mirror.clarkson.edu : SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate
warning: too many errors from mirror.clarkson.edu, skipping for the remainder of this transaction
error: failed retrieving file 'mingw-w64-ucrt-x86_64-libunistring-0.9.10-4-any.pkg.tar.zst' from mirror.clarkson.edu : SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate
error: failed retrieving file 'mingw-w64-ucrt-x86_64-brotli-1.0.9-4-any.pkg.tar.zst' from mirror.clarkson.edu : SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate
error: failed retrieving file 'mingw-w64-ucrt-x86_64-openssl-1.1.1.n-1-any.pkg.tar.zst' from fastmirror.pp.ua : SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate
error: failed retrieving file 'mingw-w64-ucrt-x86_64-libxml2-2.9.13-1-any.pkg.tar.zst' from fastmirror.pp.ua : SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate
error: failed retrieving file 'mingw-w64-ucrt-x86_64-curl-7.82.0-1-any.pkg.tar.zst' from fastmirror.pp.ua : SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate
warning: too many errors from fastmirror.pp.ua, skipping for the remainder of this transaction
error: failed retrieving file 'mingw-w64-ucrt-x86_64-libunistring-0.9.10-4-any.pkg.tar.zst' from fastmirror.pp.ua : SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate
error: failed retrieving file 'mingw-w64-ucrt-x86_64-brotli-1.0.9-4-any.pkg.tar.zst' from fastmirror.pp.ua : SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate
error: failed retrieving file 'mingw-w64-ucrt-x86_64-openssl-1.1.1.n-1-any.pkg.tar.zst' from ftp.cc.uoc.gr : SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate
error: failed retrieving file 'mingw-w64-ucrt-x86_64-libxml2-2.9.13-1-any.pkg.tar.zst' from ftp.cc.uoc.gr : SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate
error: failed retrieving file 'mingw-w64-ucrt-x86_64-curl-7.82.0-1-any.pkg.tar.zst' from ftp.cc.uoc.gr : SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate
warning: too many errors from ftp.cc.uoc.gr, skipping for the remainder of this transaction
error: failed retrieving file 'mingw-w64-ucrt-x86_64-libunistring-0.9.10-4-any.pkg.tar.zst' from ftp.cc.uoc.gr : SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate
error: failed retrieving file 'mingw-w64-ucrt-x86_64-brotli-1.0.9-4-any.pkg.tar.zst' from ftp.cc.uoc.gr : SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate
error: failed retrieving file 'mingw-w64-ucrt-x86_64-openssl-1.1.1.n-1-any.pkg.tar.zst' from mirror.jmu.edu : SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate
error: failed retrieving file 'mingw-w64-ucrt-x86_64-libxml2-2.9.13-1-any.pkg.tar.zst' from mirror.jmu.edu : SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate
error: failed retrieving file 'mingw-w64-ucrt-x86_64-curl-7.82.0-1-any.pkg.tar.zst' from mirror.jmu.edu : SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate
warning: too many errors from mirror.jmu.edu, skipping for the remainder of this transaction
error: failed retrieving file 'mingw-w64-ucrt-x86_64-libunistring-0.9.10-4-any.pkg.tar.zst' from mirror.jmu.edu : SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate
error: failed retrieving file 'mingw-w64-ucrt-x86_64-brotli-1.0.9-4-any.pkg.tar.zst' from mirror.jmu.edu : SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate
error: failed retrieving file 'mingw-w64-ucrt-x86_64-openssl-1.1.1.n-1-any.pkg.tar.zst' from mirrors.piconets.webwerks.in : SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate
error: failed retrieving file 'mingw-w64-ucrt-x86_64-libxml2-2.9.13-1-any.pkg.tar.zst' from mirrors.piconets.webwerks.in : SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate
error: failed retrieving file 'mingw-w64-ucrt-x86_64-curl-7.82.0-1-any.pkg.tar.zst' from mirrors.piconets.webwerks.in : SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate
warning: too many errors from mirrors.piconets.webwerks.in, skipping for the remainder of this transaction
error: failed retrieving file 'mingw-w64-ucrt-x86_64-libunistring-0.9.10-4-any.pkg.tar.zst' from mirrors.piconets.webwerks.in : SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate
error: failed retrieving file 'mingw-w64-ucrt-x86_64-brotli-1.0.9-4-any.pkg.tar.zst' from mirrors.piconets.webwerks.in : SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate
error: failed retrieving file 'mingw-w64-ucrt-x86_64-openssl-1.1.1.n-1-any.pkg.tar.zst' from quantum-mirror.hu : SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate
error: failed retrieving file 'mingw-w64-ucrt-x86_64-libxml2-2.9.13-1-any.pkg.tar.zst' from quantum-mirror.hu : SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate
error: failed retrieving file 'mingw-w64-ucrt-x86_64-curl-7.82.0-1-any.pkg.tar.zst' from quantum-mirror.hu : SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate
warning: too many errors from quantum-mirror.hu, skipping for the remainder of this transaction
error: failed retrieving file 'mingw-w64-ucrt-x86_64-libunistring-0.9.10-4-any.pkg.tar.zst' from quantum-mirror.hu : SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate
error: failed retrieving file 'mingw-w64-ucrt-x86_64-brotli-1.0.9-4-any.pkg.tar.zst' from quantum-mirror.hu : SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate
error: failed retrieving file 'mingw-w64-ucrt-x86_64-openssl-1.1.1.n-1-any.pkg.tar.zst' from www2.futureware.at : SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate
error: failed retrieving file 'mingw-w64-ucrt-x86_64-libxml2-2.9.13-1-any.pkg.tar.zst' from www2.futureware.at : SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate
error: failed retrieving file 'mingw-w64-ucrt-x86_64-curl-7.82.0-1-any.pkg.tar.zst' from www2.futureware.at : SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate
warning: too many errors from www2.futureware.at, skipping for the remainder of this transaction
error: failed retrieving file 'mingw-w64-ucrt-x86_64-libunistring-0.9.10-4-any.pkg.tar.zst' from www2.futureware.at : SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate
error: failed retrieving file 'mingw-w64-ucrt-x86_64-brotli-1.0.9-4-any.pkg.tar.zst' from www2.futureware.at : SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate
error: failed retrieving file 'mingw-w64-ucrt-x86_64-openssl-1.1.1.n-1-any.pkg.tar.zst' from mirrors.sjtug.sjtu.edu.cn : SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate
error: failed retrieving file 'mingw-w64-ucrt-x86_64-libxml2-2.9.13-1-any.pkg.tar.zst' from mirrors.sjtug.sjtu.edu.cn : SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate
error: failed retrieving file 'mingw-w64-ucrt-x86_64-curl-7.82.0-1-any.pkg.tar.zst' from mirrors.sjtug.sjtu.edu.cn : SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate
warning: too many errors from mirrors.sjtug.sjtu.edu.cn, skipping for the remainder of this transaction
error: failed retrieving file 'mingw-w64-ucrt-x86_64-libunistring-0.9.10-4-any.pkg.tar.zst' from mirrors.sjtug.sjtu.edu.cn : SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate
error: failed retrieving file 'mingw-w64-ucrt-x86_64-brotli-1.0.9-4-any.pkg.tar.zst' from mirrors.sjtug.sjtu.edu.cn : SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate
error: failed retrieving file 'mingw-w64-ucrt-x86_64-openssl-1.1.1.n-1-any.pkg.tar.zst' from mirrors.bit.edu.cn : SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate
error: failed retrieving file 'mingw-w64-ucrt-x86_64-libxml2-2.9.13-1-any.pkg.tar.zst' from mirrors.bit.edu.cn : SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate
error: failed retrieving file 'mingw-w64-ucrt-x86_64-curl-7.82.0-1-any.pkg.tar.zst' from mirrors.bit.edu.cn : SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate
warning: too many errors from mirrors.bit.edu.cn, skipping for the remainder of this transaction
error: failed retrieving file 'mingw-w64-ucrt-x86_64-libunistring-0.9.10-4-any.pkg.tar.zst' from mirrors.bit.edu.cn : SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate
error: failed retrieving file 'mingw-w64-ucrt-x86_64-brotli-1.0.9-4-any.pkg.tar.zst' from mirrors.bit.edu.cn : SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate
error: failed retrieving file 'mingw-w64-ucrt-x86_64-openssl-1.1.1.n-1-any.pkg.tar.zst' from repo.casualgamer.ca : SSL certificate problem: self signed certificate
error: failed retrieving file 'mingw-w64-ucrt-x86_64-libxml2-2.9.13-1-any.pkg.tar.zst' from repo.casualgamer.ca : SSL certificate problem: self signed certificate
error: failed retrieving file 'mingw-w64-ucrt-x86_64-brotli-1.0.9-4-any.pkg.tar.zst' from mirrors.aliyun.com : SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate
error: failed retrieving file 'mingw-w64-ucrt-x86_64-openssl-1.1.1.n-1-any.pkg.tar.zst' from mirror.iscas.ac.cn : SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate
error: failed retrieving file 'mingw-w64-ucrt-x86_64-libxml2-2.9.13-1-any.pkg.tar.zst' from mirror.iscas.ac.cn : SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate
error: failed retrieving file 'mingw-w64-ucrt-x86_64-curl-7.82.0-1-any.pkg.tar.zst' from mirror.iscas.ac.cn : SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate
warning: too many errors from mirror.iscas.ac.cn, skipping for the remainder of this transaction
error: failed retrieving file 'mingw-w64-ucrt-x86_64-libunistring-0.9.10-4-any.pkg.tar.zst' from mirror.iscas.ac.cn : SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate
error: failed retrieving file 'mingw-w64-ucrt-x86_64-brotli-1.0.9-4-any.pkg.tar.zst' from mirror.iscas.ac.cn : SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate
warning: failed to retrieve some files
error: failed to commit transaction (download library error)
pacman failed with the following output:
resolving dependencies...
looking for conflicting packages...

Packages (18) mingw-w64-ucrt-x86_64-brotli-1.0.9-4  mingw-w64-ucrt-x86_64-c-ares-1.18.1-1  mingw-w64-ucrt-x86_64-ca-certificates-20210119-1  mingw-w64-ucrt-x86_64-curl-7.82.0-1  mingw-w64-ucrt-x86_64-jansson-2.14-2  mingw-w64-ucrt-x86_64-jemalloc-5.2.1-2  mingw-w64-ucrt-x86_64-libffi-3.3-4  mingw-w64-ucrt-x86_64-libidn2-2.3.2-1  mingw-w64-ucrt-x86_64-libpsl-0.21.1-4  mingw-w64-ucrt-x86_64-libssh2-1.10.0-1  mingw-w64-ucrt-x86_64-libtasn1-4.18.0-1  mingw-w64-ucrt-x86_64-libunistring-0.9.10-4  mingw-w64-ucrt-x86_64-libxml2-2.9.13-1  mingw-w64-ucrt-x86_64-nghttp2-1.47.0-1  mingw-w64-ucrt-x86_64-openssl-1.1.1.n-1  mingw-w64-ucrt-x86_64-p11-kit-0.24.1-2  mingw-w64-ucrt-x86_64-xz-5.2.5-2  mingw-w64-ucrt-x86_64-libmariadbclient-3.1.13-1

Total Download Size:    11.23 MiB
Total Installed Size:  105.74 MiB

:: Proceed with installation? [Y/n]
:: Retrieving packages...
 mingw-w64-ucrt-x86_64-openssl-1.1.1.n-1-any downloading...
 mingw-w64-ucrt-x86_64-libxml2-2.9.13-1-any downloading...
 mingw-w64-ucrt-x86_64-curl-7.82.0-1-any downloading...
 mingw-w64-ucrt-x86_64-libunistring-0.9.10-4-any downloading...
 mingw-w64-ucrt-x86_64-brotli-1.0.9-4-any downloading...
Errors occurred, no packages were upgraded.
Building native extensions. This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing mysql2:
        ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    current directory: C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/mysql2-0.5.4/ext/mysql2
C:/Ruby31-x64/bin/ruby.exe -I C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/site_ruby/3.1.0 extconf.rb
checking for rb_absint_size()... yes
checking for rb_absint_singlebit_p()... yes
checking for rb_wait_for_single_fd()... yes
checking for rb_enc_interned_str() in ruby.h... yes
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
        --with-opt-dir
        --without-opt-dir
        --with-opt-include
        --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
        --with-opt-lib
        --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
        --with-make-prog
        --without-make-prog
        --srcdir=.
        --curdir
        --ruby=C:/Ruby31-x64/bin/$(RUBY_BASE_NAME)
        --with-mysql-dir
        --without-mysql-dir
        --with-mysql-include
        --without-mysql-include=${mysql-dir}/include
        --with-mysql-lib
        --without-mysql-lib=${mysql-dir}/lib
        --with-mysql-config
        --without-mysql-config
        --with-mysqlclient-dir
        --without-mysqlclient-dir
        --with-mysqlclient-include
        --without-mysqlclient-include=${mysqlclient-dir}/include
        --with-mysqlclient-lib
        --without-mysqlclient-lib=${mysqlclient-dir}/lib
        --with-mysqlclientlib
        --without-mysqlclientlib
C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/3.1.0/mkmf.rb:1086:in `block in find_library': undefined method `split' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)

    paths = paths.flat_map {|path| path.split(File::PATH_SEPARATOR)}
                                       ^^^^^^
        from C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/3.1.0/mkmf.rb:1086:in `each'
        from C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/3.1.0/mkmf.rb:1086:in `flat_map'
        from C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/3.1.0/mkmf.rb:1086:in `find_library'
        from extconf.rb:103:in `<main>'

To see why this extension failed to compile, please check the mkmf.log which can be found here:

  C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/extensions/x64-mingw-ucrt/3.1.0/mysql2-0.5.4/mkmf.log

extconf failed, exit code 1

Gem files will remain installed in C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/mysql2-0.5.4 for inspection.
Results logged to C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/extensions/x64-mingw-ucrt/3.1.0/mysql2-0.5.4/gem_make.out
```

I would really appreciate some help!
Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally figured it out. There were 2 issues:

1. I'm using a company certificate that I originally installed in ruby & rubygems dir. Apparently, that was enough for all the other gems I installed. As per [this post](https://github.com/msys2/MSYS2-packages/issues/2209#issuecomment-724135797), I also needed to install the cert in the mingw cert dir, by copying the cert to **C:\Ruby-x64\msys64\usr\ssl\certs\ca-bundle.crt**. For some reason, this affected the mysql2 gem.
2. As per the mysql2 gem, according to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9317994/3062486), (the part that discusses mysql2 gem specifically), running gem install mysql2 was not enough. I had to run

   gem install mysql2 -- '--with-mysql-lib="c:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL
   Server 8.0\lib" --with-mysql-include="c:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server
   8.0\include"'

Whew!